# Get the first element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

`array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' )`

I would like to get the first element of this array. Expected result: *string* `apple`

One requirement: *it cannot be done with passing by reference*, so `array_shift` is not a good solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean, can't be done by reference?

Comment: Function should not works using `&$array` as params.

Comment: I suspect that what you "really" mean by "can't be done by reference", is that your array is being returned dynamically from a database, and you don't want to pass the array into a variable before taking the first element from it.  If I'm right, then the vast majority of all the solutions provided to you below (including the accepted answer), are insufficient.

Comment: Do you just have to get it or get it and remove it from the existing array?

Comment: For basic use of Arrays you can review this link http://www.technofusions.com/introduction-to-arrays-in-php/

Comment: It sounds like he doesn't want the array modified because it is passed by reference.

Comment: @ray we do not need to add "PHP" to the title of every PHP question -- that is what [tag:php] tags are for.

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry first if I am misunderstanding something. But the title of the question is too generic that it shows up in the related section of some other unrelated technology like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818179/mongodb-find-all-matched-array-element-from-single-document). (even before I comment the link here). That's why I thought it would do no harm to make this question more specific in the title.

Comment: @ray the Related list is often horrible for PHP pages.  The Linked list contains this page because there is a hyperlink on this page that connects to that page.

Answer (score 1659, accepted):

Original answer, but costly (O(n)):

```
array_shift(array_values($array));
```

In O(1):

```
array_pop(array_reverse($array));
```

**Other use cases, etc...**

If modifying (in the sense of resetting array pointers) of `$array` is not a problem, you might use:

```
reset($array);
```

This should be theoretically more efficient, if a array "copy" is needed:

```
array_shift(array_slice($array, 0, 1));
```

With PHP 5.4+ (but might cause an index error if empty):

```
array_values($array)[0];
```

Comment: +1 for the clever workaround to prevent modifying the original array with array_values()

Comment: I get this: <b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference. Nice workaround btw

Comment: Isn't this a little overkill? What if the array contains several thousands of elements? Is it justified to create a whole new array just to get its first element? `list()` and `reset()` are much nicer solutions to my opinion.

Comment: +1 because this works event with array_keys if I need the first key

Comment: yes, overkill workaround, just the reset PHP built-in function, as mentionned after.

Comment: I agree. Total overkill and extraordinary resource heavy compared to one line which resets and returns the current value: reset($array);

Comment: -1 As the above commenters have said. It's baffling to me that this has 101 upvotes.

Comment: This answer is even more incorrect, if the assumption I make in my comment to the original question is correct.

Comment: array_shift(array_slice($array,0,1)) // <-- in theory faster as it considers only the first element

Comment: First of all it doesn't run with Strict Standards as said before. Using reset() (and key() after it, if necessary) is a much more graceful and performant option.

Comment: The reset(&$arr) post below is far more efficient.

Comment: There's a fine line between avoiding premature optimization and senseless resource waste.

Comment: THIS WRONG! USE echo reset($arr);

Comment: @albanx If you want the key use the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array).

Comment: +1 for array_values solution as it does not modify the original array

Comment: I am completely flabbergasted by the fact that in 2014 we can't get better than a reset function that cannot be used with passed by reference value. PHP should really consider separating array into lists and dictionnaries.

Comment: there is an offset problem with `array_values($arr)[0]` in case the input array `$arr` is empty.

Comment: All I needed was array_slice. The other stuff was unnecessary for me. Thanks!

Comment: the correct and simplest answer is the one below, e.g: current($arr);

Comment: This is where community based moderation should come into play.  The selected answer does this the wrong way, yet receives hundreds of upvotes anyway.   The best answer is one posted by user `lepe` below.

Comment: @acoder not sure what you mean: my/this answer covers different use cases, including the one using `reset`?!

Comment: I don't understand everybody complaining about this answer. `reset` CHANGES the array by reseting its internal pointer, so if you use `reset` method within a loop using internal array's pointer, then it'll mess-up the expected loop behavior and could make it run forever. As said by the author, if you do not care about the pointer, then `reset` is the way to go, else it is definitely not an option

Comment: The problem here is that array_shift is expensive on large arrays. It is better to use `array_pop(array_reverse($array))`. Also, the OP just says that they want the first value, not to loop through them all, so the cost of `array_shift` provides no benefit.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array/43749334#43749334) for the ultimate solution. Feel free to integrate it in this answer.

Comment: I cannot understand how `array_reverse($array)` could be O(1).

Comment: @blueyed how is possible for array_reverse to be O(1)?, it creates a new array, it forces the function to be at least O(n).

Comment: As @ntd said, I think is not O(1). If you take a look in the implementation, you can see a loop in both case of the `if`:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5a31e14beba625f1b32d61d6aec85b3df7f023cc/ext/standard/array.c#L4248

Comment: array_shift = O(n), array_pop = O(1), array_values = O(n), array_reverse = O(n). Then: array_shift(array_values()) = O(n + n) = O(n), array_pop(array_reverse()) = O(1 + n) = O(n)

Comment: starting from PHP8 this construction is a bug: $array[0]  Keys can be negative, so you never know if first element is not  $array[-30]

Comment: From PHP 7.3 you can use `array_key_first`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php

Comment: with php 7.3.2 your `array_pop(array_reverse($array))` throws **only variables can be passed by reference**

Comment: 1531 upvotes? A perfect demonstration on why democracy fails

Comment: array_pop() pops the last element of array If you use php 8 array_pop pops by referenced array So it accepts varable. You can store the reversed array in a variable then array_pop the reversed array.

Answer (score 902):

As Mike pointed out (the easiest possible way):

```
$arr = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
echo reset($arr); // Echoes "apple"
```

If you want to get the key: (execute it after reset)

```
echo key($arr); // Echoes "4"
```

From [PHP's documentation](https://www.php.net/reset):

> *mixed* **reset** ( array | object *&$array* );

Description:

> **reset()** rewinds *array's* internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is
> empty.

Comment: Although it is passed by reference to reset, the original array is not modified. I'm guessing that's the reason hsz does not want to pass it by reference..?

Comment: The array's iterator is modified.  If you do this in a `foreach` with the subject array, you'll screw it up.

Comment: @Zenexer this is not always (usually) true. Usually in practise, `foreach` will copy the array which is it looping through.

Comment: what if I want to get the '4' (assign name) values?

Comment: @Angger after reset, you can call `key($arr)` and you will get '4' (added into answer)

Comment: Neither @Zenexer nor Luke Cousins are right: 
1) foreach does not use internat pointer of an array - instead it creates it's own pointer. It is easy to check calling reset inside foreach - the loop will follow it's way with no effect from `reset()`.
2) No, foreach DOES NOT create a copy of an array!!! It only creates it's own pointer (not even a copy of an existing one - it is also easy to check, calling `next()` before foreach).

Comment: @dmikam Years later, I realize that’s definitely a possibility, though I haven’t tested it. I’ll take your word for it.

Comment: @Zenexer Well, you don't have to take my word :) It is pretty well describet in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14854568/2828391

Comment: What if the array is empty? `reset()` will return `false`, which may lead to bugs if you expect the array to contain `bool` values.

Comment: @Jacob In such cases, you would check if an array is empty before calling this function.

Answer (score 320):

```
$first_value = reset($array); // First element's value
$first_key = key($array); // First element's key
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested it, but it seems this approach would be the most efficient.

Comment: Only problem is the question asked for the value, not the key. Thus current($array) should be used instead of of key($array)

Comment: @zmonteca $first_value = reset($array); here you get the value, reset() function rewinds arrays internal pointer and returns first element.

Comment: the best answer! was looking for key() equivalence to get  the first value. This helps!

Comment: What if the array is empty? `reset()` will return `false`, which may lead to bugs if you expect the array to contain `bool` values.

Comment: crazy that an answere that came up with the same solution as a poster seven month before, gets so many likes....

Answer (score 161):

`current($array)`

returns the first element of an array, [according to the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php).

> Every array has an internal pointer to its "current" element, which is initialized to the first element inserted into the array.

So it works until you have re-positioned the array pointer, and otherwise you'll have to use `reset()` which ll rewind array and ll return first element of array

[According to the PHP manual reset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

> reset() rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element.

Examples of `current()` and `reset()`

```
$array = array('step one', 'step two', 'step three', 'step four');

// by default, the pointer is on the first element
echo current($array) . "<br />\n"; // "step one"

//Forward the array pointer and then reset it

// skip two steps
next($array);
next($array);
echo current($array) . "<br />\n"; // "step three"

// reset pointer, start again on step one
echo reset($array) . "<br />\n"; // "step one"
```

Comment: I don't know why this wasn't the accepted answer, as it answers the question fairly simply and accurately.

Comment: ```current($array)``` will only work if the array pointer is "currently" pointing to the first element, otherwise ```reset($array)``` would be required.

Comment: It seems `current()` no longer requires a reference, although the PHP docs do not reflect this. So I think this has become the best solution.

Comment: @Ryan agreed, but this solution was given 2 years prior to 2014 in [this other answer of this same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11883690/6225838)... Weird that this incomplete sentence got more upvotes.

Comment: What if the array is empty? `reset()` and `current()` will return `false`, which may lead to bugs if you expect the array to contain `bool` values.

Comment: Different horses for courses. `reset()` if you have an array variable. `current()` when nesting functions e.g. `current(array_column([],'key'))`

Answer (score 116):

```
$arr = $array = array( 9 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
echo reset($arr); // echoes 'apple'
```

If you don't want to lose the current pointer position, just create an alias for the array.

Comment: didn't get it, what do you mean? It works fine whether the key of the first is bigger than the other ones.

Comment: +1 FYI `reset()` already returns the first element, so there is no need to use `current()` -- `echo reset($arr)` should suffice

Comment: @Mike but you might prefer `current` to `reset` to avoid PHP notice/error produced in reference cases, e.g. [`current(array_filter(...));` in 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/sUrcB).

Comment: What if the array is empty? `reset()` will return `false`, which may lead to bugs if you expect the array to contain `bool` values.

Answer (score 94):

**PHP 7.3** added two functions for getting the first and the last key of an array *directly* without modification of the original array and without creating any temporary objects:

- **[array_key_first](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php)**
- **[array_key_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php)**

Apart from being semantically meaningful, these functions don't even move the array pointer (as `foreach` would do).

Having the keys, one can get the values by the keys directly.

---

### Examples (all of them require PHP 7.3+)

#### Getting the first/last key and value:

```
$my_array = ['IT', 'rules', 'the', 'world'];

$first_key = array_key_first($my_array);
$first_value = $my_array[$first_key];

$last_key = array_key_last($my_array);
$last_value = $my_array[$last_key];
```

#### Getting the first/last value as one-liners, *assuming the array cannot be empty*:

```
$first_value = $my_array[ array_key_first($my_array) ];

$last_value = $my_array[ array_key_last($my_array) ];
```

#### Getting the first/last value as one-liners, with defaults for empty arrays:

```
$first_value = empty($my_array) ? 'default' : $my_array[ array_key_first($my_array) ];

$last_value = empty($my_array) ? 'default' : $my_array[ array_key_last($my_array) ];
```

Comment: Shorten with [null-coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), usually null is default so:

`$first_value = $my_array[array_key_first($my_array)] ?? null;`

Comment: From PHP 7.3, this should be the selected answer.

Comment: They should add `array_first` too. To get first item. And possibly `array_second` ;)

Answer (score 76):

You can get the Nth element with a language construct, "list":

```
// First item
list($firstItem) = $yourArray;

// First item from an array that is returned from a function
list($firstItem) = functionThatReturnsArray();

// Second item
list( , $secondItem) = $yourArray;
```

With the `array_keys` function you can do the same for keys:

```
list($firstKey) = array_keys($yourArray);
list(, $secondKey) = array_keys($yourArray);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do: `list($first_value) = $my_array;` In my opinion, the very best option. It does not have the issues from the other answers presented here: no "overkill" because it does not copy or the array or create a new one. No "references": the array is not modified. No "reset": no changes to the array internal pointer...

Comment: Very elegant solution, but throws an E_NOTICE when the array is empty.

Comment: @Tgr that can be easily overcome by checking if `count($array) > 0`.

Comment: @Mike yes, but then it is not so elegant anymore :)

Comment: Isn't this wrong?! It works only if array keys are `int`, try doing `list($firstItem) = array('key1' => 'value1');` and you will get an error `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: @MarcoDemaio, you're correct, but you can always use array_values() function in such cases: list($firstItem) = array_values($yourArray);

Comment: @Sergiy but then you loose the biggest advantage of this solution, and that's not copying the entire original array to another needlessly.  Still, +1 for the benefits assuming you can guarantee an integer indexed array

Comment: To clarify: `list($x) = foo();` is equivalent to `$x = foo()[0];`. Note that this is not necessarily the same as "get the first item", since even an integer-indexed array may not have an element with key 0. In my case I was doing "list($order) = get_order($user);" but "get_order" was returning orders keyed by their ID, which was usually not 0. As @Sergiy says, array_values() fixes this, but detracts from the efficiency and (more importantly) readability of the code.

Answer (score 56):

PHP 5.4+:

```
array_values($array)[0];
```

Comment: He edited his answer in Oct-2013 to include my answer that I added in April.

Comment: PHP 4: `$array_values = array_values($array); $value = $array_values[0];`

Comment: if the array is empty it will return `undefined key 0` so use it with caution

Answer (score 29):

Some arrays don't work with functions like `list`, `reset` or `current`. Maybe they're "faux" arrays - partially implementing ArrayIterator, for example.

If you want to pull the first value regardless of the array, you can short-circuit an iterator:

```
foreach($array_with_unknown_keys as $value) break;
```

Your value will then be available in `$value` and the loop will break after the first iteration. This is more efficient than copying a potentially large array to a function like array_unshift(array_values($arr)).

You can grab the key this way too:

```
foreach($array_with_unknown_keys as $key=>$value) break;
```

If you're calling this from a function, simply return early:

```
function grab_first($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $value) return $value;
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is one of the fastest ways because using the language construct foreach rather than a function call (which is more expensive).    http://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-get-the-first-element-of-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 28):

Suppose:

```
$array = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
```

Just use:

```
$array[key($array)]
```

to get first element or

```
key($array)
```

to get first key.

Or you can unlink the first if you want to remove it.

Comment: Wht not simply use `current` then?

Answer (score 22):

From [Laravel's helpers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php):

```
function head($array)
{
    return reset($array);
}
```

The array being passed by value to the function, the [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) affects the internal pointer of a copy of the array, and it doesn't touch the original
array (note it returns `false` if the array is empty).

Usage example:

```
$data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

current($data); // foo
next($data); // bar
head($data); // foo
next($data); // baz
```

Also, here is an alternative. It's *very marginally* faster, but more interesting. It lets easily change the default value if the array is empty:

```
function head($array, $default = null)
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        return $item;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

---

For the record, here is [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687358/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-without-deleting-it/45333947#45333947), for the array's last element.

Answer (score 17):

Keep this simple! There are lots of correct answers here, but to minimize all the confusion, these two work and reduce a lot of overhead:

`key($array)` gets the first key of an array 
`current($array)` gets the first value of an array

**EDIT:**
Regarding the comments below. The following example will output: `string(13) "PHP code test"`

```
$array = array
(
   '1'           => 'PHP code test',  
   'foo'         => 'bar', 5 , 5 => 89009, 
   'case'        => 'Random Stuff: '.rand(100,999),
   'PHP Version' => phpversion(),
   0             => 'ending text here'
);

var_dump(current($array));
```

Comment: Uhh. `current` equals current element. You have to reset the pointer to the beginning of the array to ensure it is actually at the beginning.

Comment: current () will get the current element, not the first element. It's different.

Comment: current will work if there is only one element in the array.

Comment: @tfont, what happens if you add the line `next($array);` immediately before the `var_dump` line? I'm pretty sure you'll get `string(3) "bar"` and that's not "the first value of an array".

Answer (score 14):

```
$arr = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
foreach($arr as $first) break;
echo $first;
```

Output:

```
apple
```

Answer (score 14):

Simply do:

```
array_shift(array_slice($array,0,1));
```

Comment: It is an unattractive (and unexplained) technique since there are single-call techniques to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 12):

I would do `echo current($array)` .

Comment: @hsz Doesn't matter, `current()` doesn't error when non-references are passed. Provided that the pointer is still at the beginning this works.

Comment: but it produces a Notice which makes your logs dirty and well... you should get rid of Notices also wven if they are not critical

Comment: @dmikam no it does not. Actually `reset` produces the "Only variables should be passed by reference" notice while `current` does not: [Online PHP Editor example of `current(array_filter(...));`](https://3v4l.org/sUrcB).

Comment: @CPHPython, seems like you are right... looks like I had this idea of current from old times of PHP 4 where it really produces Fatal error: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5efb3f322b15cbb3938c2729d6de97f7d73bc90c

The only issue I see in using current is that it does not guarantee that the returned element is the first element of an array (internal pointer may be modified by the called function). Virtually it may return random element of an array.

Comment: @dmikam I was never able to return a random element of an array with `current`... Here's an [3v4l example](https://3v4l.org/B38nJ) that adds an element, sorts the array and removes the 0 indexed element => it always returned the first element. Can you back up your possibility with an example?

Comment: @CPHPython A bit artificial example, but it demonstrates well my thoughts: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a30f92a932a31fbd7d3191435a481336f40ac4bc

just imagine that you receive your array from some function that uses `next()`, `end()` or any other function that modifies array's internal pointer. In my example, `current()` returns null because the internal pointer is "out of range" of array. But it may 'virtually' point to any/random element too.

Answer (score 11):

**PHP 7.3** added two functions for getting the first and the last key of an array *directly* without modification of the original array and without creating any temporary objects:

- **[array_key_first](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php)**
- **[array_key_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php)**

"There are several ways to provide this functionality for versions prior to PHP 7.3.0. It is possible to use array_keys(), but that may be rather inefficient. It is also possible to use reset() and key(), but that may change the internal array pointer. An efficient solution, which does not change the internal array pointer, written as polyfill:"

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('array_key_first')) {
    function array_key_first($arr) {
        foreach($arr as $key => $unused) {
            return $key;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

if (!function_exists('array_key_last')) {
    function array_key_last($arr) {
        return array_key_first(array_reverse($arr, true));
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$myArray = array (4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum');
$arrayKeys = array_keys($myArray);

// The first element of your array is:
echo $myArray[$arrayKeys[0]];
```

Answer (score 8):

A kludgy way is:

```
$foo = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );

function get_first ($foo) {
    foreach ($foo as $k=>$v){
        return $v;
    }
}

print get_first($foo);
```

Comment: At least you're honest - it's kludgy!  But, it works, and I've used it in the past until learning the list() technique above.

Comment: If you are doing this, you might as well use `reset()` as the array pointer is reset before `foreach`is called anyway.

Answer (score 8):

```
$array=array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );

$firstValue = each($array)[1];
```

This is much more efficient than `array_values()` because the `each()` function does not copy the entire array.

For more info see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Comment: `because the each() function does not copy the entire array.` +1

Comment: But the thing is that you should do a reset before, if the internal pointer is not at the beginning you are not going to get the first element.

Comment: But each() receives an array by reference and the requirement of the initial questions is not to do so

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
$first = array_slice($array, 0, 1);  
$val= $first[0];
```

By default, `array_slice` does not preserve keys, so we can safely use zero as the index.

Answer (score 6):

**Most of these work! BUT for a quick single line (low resource) call:**

```
$array = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
echo $array[key($array)];

// key($array) -> will return the first key (which is 4 in this example)
```

Although this works, and decently well, please also see my additional answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410351/1804013

Comment: This is equivalent to using `current($array)`, which requires that the array's internal pointer be at the first element anyway, in which case, `echo reset($array)` is most appropriate.

Comment: @Tyzoid he actually wrote [another answer here with your suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410351/6225838), but he omitted your explanation... Thank you.

Comment: @Tyzoid: I made an additional answer/update awhile go:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410351/1804013

Answer (score 4):

I think using [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) would be your best bet here. You could return the value at index zero from the result of that function to get 'apple'.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little late to the game, but I was presented with a problem where my array contained array elements as children inside it, and thus I couldn't just get a string representation of the first array element. By [using PHP's `current()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), I managed this:

```
<?php
    $original = array(4 => array('one', 'two'), 7 => array('three', 'four'));
    reset($original);  // to reset the internal array pointer...
    $first_element = current($original);  // get the current element...
?>
```

Thanks to all the current solutions helped me get to this answer, I hope this helps someone sometime!

Answer (score 4):

```php
<?php
    $arr = array(3 => "Apple", 5 => "Ball", 11 => "Cat");
    echo array_values($arr)[0]; // Outputs: Apple
?>
```

Other Example:

```php
<?php
    $arr = array(3 => "Apple", 5 => "Ball", 11 => "Cat");
    echo current($arr); // Outputs: Apple
    echo reset($arr); // Outputs: Apple
    echo next($arr); // Outputs: Ball
    echo current($arr); // Outputs: Ball
    echo reset($arr); // Outputs: Apple
?>
```

Comment: What part of this answer brings new information to the page?

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions for you.

Solution 1 - Just use the key. You have not said that you can not use it. :)

```
<?php
    // Get the first element of this array.
    $array = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );

    // Gets the first element by key
    $result = $array[4];

    // Expected result: string apple
    assert('$result === "apple" /* Expected result: string apple. */');
?>
```

Solution 2 - array_flip() + key()

```
<?php
    // Get first element of this array. Expected result: string apple
    $array = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );

    // Turn values to keys
    $array = array_flip($array);

    // You might thrown a reset in just to make sure
    // that the array pointer is at the first element.
    // Also, reset returns the first element.
    // reset($myArray);

    // Return the first key
    $firstKey = key($array);

    assert('$firstKey === "apple" /* Expected result: string apple. */');
?>
```

Solution 3 - array_keys()

```
echo $array[array_keys($array)[0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the author just was looking for a way to get the first element of an array after getting it from some function ([mysql_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), for example) without generating a STRICT "Only variables should be passed by reference".

If it so, almost all the ways described here will get this message... and some of them uses a lot of additional memory duplicating an array (or some part of it). An easy way to avoid it is just assigning the value inline before calling any of those functions:

```
$first_item_of_array = current($tmp_arr = mysql_fetch_row(...));
// or
$first_item_of_array = reset($tmp_arr = func_get_my_huge_array());
```

This way you don't get the STRICT message on screen, nor in logs, and you don't create any additional arrays. It works with **both indexed AND associative** arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like fiddling with the array's internal pointer, but it's also inefficient to build a second array with `array_keys()` or `array_values()`, so I usually define this:

```
function array_first(array $f) {
    foreach ($f as $v) {
        return $v;
    }
    throw new Exception('array was empty');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No one has suggested using the ArrayIterator class:

```
$array = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
$first_element = (new ArrayIterator($array))->current();
echo $first_element; //'apple'
```

gets around the by reference stipulation of the OP.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Also works to get the first key: `(new ArrayIterator($array))->key()`. Note that it correctly returns `null` for both value and key when the array is empty (rather than returning a pseudo-value like `false`). Unfortunately doesn't work for Laravel's Collection class though, it always returns `null`

Answer (score 1):

This is not so simple response in the real world. Suppose that we have these examples of possible responses that you can find in some libraries.

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4);
$array3 = array('hello'=>'world', 'foo'=>'bar');
$array4 = null;

var_dump('reset1', reset($array1));
var_dump('reset2', reset($array2));
var_dump('reset3', reset($array3));
var_dump('reset4', reset($array4)); // Warning

var_dump('array_shift1', array_shift($array1));
var_dump('array_shift2', array_shift($array2));
var_dump('array_shift3', array_shift($array3));
var_dump('array_shift4', array_shift($array4)); // Warning

var_dump('each1', each($array1));
var_dump('each2', each($array2));
var_dump('each3', each($array3));
var_dump('each4', each($array4)); // Warning

var_dump('array_values1', array_values($array1)[0]); // Notice
var_dump('array_values2', array_values($array2)[0]);
var_dump('array_values3', array_values($array3)[0]);
var_dump('array_values4', array_values($array4)[0]); // Warning

var_dump('array_slice1', array_slice($array1, 0, 1));
var_dump('array_slice2', array_slice($array2, 0, 1));
var_dump('array_slice3', array_slice($array3, 0, 1));
var_dump('array_slice4', array_slice($array4, 0, 1)); // Warning

list($elm) = $array1; // Notice
var_dump($elm);
list($elm) = $array2;
var_dump($elm);
list($elm) = $array3; // Notice
var_dump($elm);
list($elm) = $array4;
var_dump($elm);
```

Like you can see, we have several 'one line' solutions that work well in some cases, but not in all.

In my opinion, you have should that handler only with arrays.

Now talking about performance, assuming that we have always array, like this:

```
$elm = empty($array) ? null : ...($array);

...you would use without errors:
$array[count($array)-1];
array_shift
reset
array_values
array_slice
```

`array_shift` is faster than `reset`, that is more fast than [count()-1], and these three are faster than `array_values` and `array_slice`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`array_keys()`** to access the keys of your associative array as a numerical indexed array, which is then again can be used as key for the array.

**When the solution is `arr[0]`**:

> (Note, that since the array with the keys is 0-based index, the 1st
>   element is index 0)

You can use a variable and then subtract one, to get your logic, that `1 => 'apple'`.

```
$i = 1;
$arr = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
echo $arr[array_keys($arr)[$i-1]];
```

**Output:**

```
apple
```

Well, for simplicity- just use:

```
$arr = array( 4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum' );
echo $arr[array_keys($arr)[0]];
```

**Output:**

```
apple
```

**By the first method not just the first element, but can treat an associative array like an indexed array.**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first element by using this coding:

```
$array_key_set = array_keys($array);
$first_element = $array[$array_key_set[0]];
```

Or use:

```
$i=0;
foreach($array as $arr)
{
  if($i==0)
  {
    $first_element=$arr;
    break;
  }
 $i++;
}
echo $first_element;
```

Comment: Why not just break out of the loop? `foreach ($array as $arr) { $first_element = $arr; break; }`

Comment: The `$i` if statements are completely irrelevant, and you can simply exclude them all together. `$i` will ALWAYS be 0 on the first loop, it will ALWAYS break out before ever reaching `$i++;`

Comment: Completely equivalent to return $array[0];

Answer (score 1):

One line closure, copy, reset:

```
<?php

$fruits = array(4 => 'apple', 7 => 'orange', 13 => 'plum');

echo (function() use ($fruits) { return reset($fruits); })();
```

Output:

```
apple
```

Alternatively the shorter short arrow function:

```
echo (fn() => reset($fruits))();
```

This uses by-value variable binding as above.  Both will not mutate the original pointer.

Comment: Note `$copy = $fruits; echo reset($copy);` is far more portable accross Php versions.

Comment: If you don't care about the original pointer.  `reset($fruits)` will do!

Answer (score 0):

A small change to what Sarfraz posted is:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$output = array_slice($array, 0, 1);
print_r ($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the "list" example, but "list" only works on the left-hand-side of an assignment. If we don't want to assign a variable, we would be forced to make up a temporary name, which at best pollutes our scope and at worst overwrites an existing value:

```
list($x) = some_array();
var_dump($x);
```

The above will overwrite any existing value of $x, and the $x variable will hang around as long as this scope is active (the end of this function/method, or forever if we're in the top-level). This can be worked around using call_user_func and an anonymous function, but it's clunky:

```
var_dump(call_user_func(function($arr) { list($x) = $arr; return $x; },
                        some_array()));
```

If we use anonymous functions like this, we can actually get away with reset and array_shift, even though they use pass-by-reference. This is because calling a function will bind its arguments, and these arguments can be passed by reference:

```
var_dump(call_user_func(function($arr) { return reset($arr); },
                        array_values(some_array())));
```

However, this is actually overkill, since call_user_func will perform this temporary assignment internally. This lets us treat pass-by-reference functions as if they were pass-by-value, without any warnings or errors:

```
var_dump(call_user_func('reset', array_values(some_array())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also worth bearing in mind is the context in which you're doing this, as an exhaustive check can be expensive and not always necessary.

For example, this solution works fine for the situation in which I'm using it (but obviously it can't be relied on in all cases...)

```
 /**
 * A quick and dirty way to determine whether the passed in array is associative or not, assuming that either:<br/>
 * <br/>
 * 1) All the keys are strings - i.e. associative<br/>
 * or<br/>
 * 2) All the keys are numeric - i.e. not associative<br/>
 *
 * @param array $objects
 * @return boolean
 */
private function isAssociativeArray(array $objects)
{
    // This isn't true in the general case, but it's a close enough (and quick) approximation for the context in
    // which we're using it.

    reset($objects);
    return count($objects) > 0 && is_string(key($objects));
}
```

Comment: What about `array(13, 'foo' => 'bar')` ?

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't work in all cases, but it's much cheaper than most of the other solutions and works fine in many (perhaps even most?) of the situations in which you're likely to need it.  Please see the assumptions in the method comment.

Answer (score 0):

Nice one with a combination of `array_slice` and `implode`:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
echo implode(array_slice($arr, 0, 1));
// Outputs 1

/*---------------------------------*/

$arr = array(
    'key_1' => 'One',
    'key_2' => 'Two',
    'key_3' => 'Three',
);
echo implode(array_slice($arr, 0, 1));
// Outputs One
```

Answer (score -3):

There are too many answers here, and the selected answer will work for most of the cases.

In my case, I had a 2D array, and `array_values` for some odd reason was removing the keys on the inner arrays. So I end up with this:

```
$keys = array_keys($myArray); // Fetches all the keys
$firstElement = $myArray[$keys[0]]; // Get the first element using first key
```

Answer (score -9):

If you are using `Laravel` you can do:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$first = collect($array)->first();
```

Comment: There is no reason to use framework helpers when there are native functions that can do the same.

Comment: This is actually correct if you are using Laravel and your array is already in a collection.

Answer (score -10):

Finding the first and last items in an array:

```
// Get the first item in the array
print $array[0]; // Prints 1

// Get the last item in the array
print end($array);
```

Comment: This will only work if you have an array that has consecutively numbered keys, beginning with 0 and ending with count()-1. It won't work in the case of the OP's array.

Comment: Also even when using numeric keys it isn't said that zero is the first key. The order of adding is important.

```php
$x = [1 => 'one', 0 => 'zero'];
var_dump(reset($x));
string(3) "one"
```