# When using [] to dynamically set array values, how do you get the last key that was filled?

Tags: php, arrays, key

When using `[]` to dynamically set array values, how do you get the last key that was filled?

For example, consider:

```
$array[] = 'apple';
$array[] = 'banana';
$array[] = 'orange';
```

How do you get the last key value (in this case `2` for "orange")?

The `key()` function is just returning `0` no matter which line I place it after.

Comment: You could use count($array) and decrease the value by 1

Comment: @asprin: That will only work for numerically indexed arrays.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687358/best-way-to-get-last-element-of-an-array-w-o-deleting-it

Comment: @Jon: that's what the OP posted...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: If the array includes any elements with non-numeric keys (perhaps added earlier), or if elements are later removed, counting will not work. And there is really no reason to use a "worse" version.

Comment: @Jon While that is true, I gave the OP the simplest solution. There are a number of ways in which a solution can be obtained. Also my answer was based on they array which the OP listed. And since my answer is not the ideal one, I only put it up as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
<?php

    $array[] = 'apple';
    $array[] = 'banana';
    $array[] = 'orange';

    $count = count($array);

    $last_key = $count-1;

    $last_value = $array[$last_key];

?>
```

Comment: I'm selecting your solution both because it's simple and because it can be done in one line: `$last_value = $array[count($array)-1]`  Thanks!

Comment: yes that's right but I coded by that way to give more details for reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
end($array);
echo key($array);
```

is all you should need.

You could also use the purpose built `array_search('orange',$array)` if you already know the last value you entered and only need the key.

Comment: @Programmer But it edited the array, and this does not. Also, it returned the value, and OP needs the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last key with [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php), but you need to call [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) first:

```
echo key(end($array));
```

An alternative solution (which is less performant) is to use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and get the last element:

```
echo end(array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use end function

```
<?php
end($array);
key($array);
```

or just try this

```
echo count($array);
```