# json_decode: array_reduce stopped working

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-reduce

```
<?php
$json = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=e1Sw66C3";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($json), true);

$data = $data['recenttracks'];
$tracks=$data['track'];

 foreach ($tracks as $track) {
    $artist = $track['artist']['#text'];
    $title = $track['name'];
    $url = $track['url'];
    $image = array_reduce($track['image'], function ($image, array $i) { return $image ?: ($i['size'] == 'large' ? $i['#text'] : null); });
echo '<li><a rel="external nofollow" href="'.htmlentities($url, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'" title="', $title, '">', $artist, ' - ', $title, '</a></li>'; }
echo ($image);
?>
```

This snippet has always worked. Now I don't know why BOOM `echo ($image);` outputs nothing.
I can't figure out what's wrong with that function. The rest of the code works fine (the other info taken from the input). You can check the input by going to the link in `file_get_contents`.

Comment: It works and outputs the list.

Comment: seems to work ... http://codepad.viper-7.com/bM2hXD

Comment: You turned on error reporting in your hosting environment? (`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`) as it's working for everyone else.

Comment: @cheery and Ghost yep the list is returned. I'm saying the problem is just with $image, which outputs nothing. The other variables are ok.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno list is displayed, not just returned

Comment: The problem is with $image. It should return an url (see the Json input).

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno because you overwrite `$image` in every loop. This code could not work from the beginning.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno just explain what you want to get? It was 'working' previously, probably because element with `large` was the last. Otherwise `$image` is changing every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, previously your code was working only because element with `size = 'large'` was the last one, otherwise variable `$image` is overwritten at every loop. What you need is something like this

```
$json = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=e1Sw66C3";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($json), true);

$data = $data['recenttracks'];
$tracks=$data['track'];
$images = array();

 foreach ($tracks as $track) {
    $artist = $track['artist']['#text'];
    $title = $track['name'];
    $url = $track['url'];
    if (isset($track['image']) && is_array($track['image']))
       foreach($track['image'] as $image)
          if (isset($image['size']) && $image['size'] == 'large' &&
              isset($image['#text']) && !empty($image['#text']))
             $images[] = $image['#text'];

    echo '<li><a rel="external nofollow" href="' . 
          htmlentities($url, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '" title="', $title, '">',
          $artist, ' - ', $title, '</a></li>'; 
}
echo join("\n", $images);
```

Comment: I'll try in some hours! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks!!! It works! Just one last thing! How can I extract just the last ("large") image from the array?

Comment: `end($images)`, for example + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687358/best-way-to-get-last-element-of-an-array-w-o-deleting-it

Comment: You mean `echo end($images);` instead of `echo join("\n", $images);` at the end? `echo end(array_values($images));` outputs nothing

Comment: Did I write anything about `array_values`?? `echo end($images);`

Comment: Because the last element is empty, let me check why. Because in the original data there are empty values. They can be skipped by additional condition - added it to the updated answer.

Comment: And yes and no. First of all, it rewrites $images at every loop, second - it will work only if the last element of the loop has requires size = large in it. Otherwise it is rewritten by null. Even if the last element is not empty, but does not have size = large, you will get nothing.