# php pop/push/shift/unshift, which to use for queues and which for stacks

Tags: php, stack, queue

In PHP there are two ways to use an array as a **stack** (LIFO)
and two ways to use them as a **queue** (FIFO).

One could implement a **stack** with `push` & `pop`,
but the same can be done with `unshift` & `shift`.

Similarly one could implement a **queue** with `push` & `shift`,
but the same can be done with `unshift` & `pop`.

To demonstrate:

```
echo "stack push & pop approach:\n";
$s = []; array_push($s, 'first'); array_push($s, 'second'); array_push($s, 'third');
echo     array_pop($s) . '-' .    array_pop($s) . '-' .     array_pop($s) .  "\n";
echo "stack unshift & shift approach:\n";
$s = []; array_unshift($s, 'first'); array_unshift($s, 'second'); array_unshift($s, 'third');
echo     array_shift($s) . '-' .     array_shift($s) . '-' .      array_shift($s) .  "\n";
echo "queue push & shift approach:\n";
$q = []; array_push($q, 'first'); array_push($q, 'second'); array_push($q, 'third');
echo     array_shift($q) . '-' .  array_shift($q) . '-' .   array_shift($q) .  "\n";
echo "queue unshift & pop approach:\n";
$q = []; array_unshift($q, 'first'); array_unshift($q, 'second'); array_unshift($q, 'third');
echo     array_pop($q) . '-' .       array_pop($q) . '-' .        array_pop($q) .       "\n";
```

Which outputs:

```
stack push & pop approach:
third-second-first
stack unshift & shift approach:
third-second-first
queue push & shift approach:
first-second-third
queue unshift & pop approach:
first-second-third
```

So which sets of functions to use?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

For **stack**s use `push` & `pop` (add to end, take from end).

For **queue**s use `push` & `shift` (add to end, take from beginning).

## Considerations

### Documentation

When considering the PHP documentation as of today 2016-12-29 for these functions we find this:

For [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):
the **description** mentions "*array_push() treats array as a stack*"
and the **example** uses "*`$stack`*".

For [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php):
the **description** mentions nothing on stacks or queues
and the **example** uses "*`$stack`*".

For [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):
the **description** mentions nothing on stacks or queues (but mentions required reindexing)
and the **example** uses "*`$stack`*".

For [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):
the **description** mentions nothing on stacks or queues (but mentions required reindexing)
and the **example** uses "*`$queue`*".

So this suggests using `push` & `pop` for stacks (based on mention in description)
and suggests using `unshift` & `pop` for queues (based on only mention of queue in examples).

This seems a bit thin... A suggestion to improve the documentation has been submitted here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73839

### Performance

Running this:

```
echo "\nstack push & pop approach     :  ";
$a=[];$i=0;$t=microtime(true); while($i<100000) { array_push($a, 'dummy'); array_pop($a); ++$i; }; echo (microtime(true) - $t);
echo "\nstack unshift & shift approach:  ";
$a=[];$i=0;$t=microtime(true); while($i<100000) { array_unshift($a, 'dummy'); array_shift($a); ++$i; }; echo (microtime(true) - $t);
echo "\nqueue push & shift approach   :  ";
$a=[];$i=0;$t=microtime(true); while($i<100000) { array_push($a, 'dummy'); array_shift($a); ++$i; }; echo (microtime(true) - $t);
echo "\nqueue unshift & pop approach  :  ";
$a=[];$i=0;$t=microtime(true); while($i<100000) { array_unshift($a, 'dummy'); array_pop($a); ++$i; }; echo (microtime(true) - $t);
```

Returns this:

```
stack push & pop approach     :  0.011210918426514
stack unshift & shift approach:  0.015399217605591
queue push & shift approach   :  0.011627912521362
queue unshift & pop approach  :  0.015273094177246
```

For **stack**s this suggests to use `push` & `pop`: natural terminology, matching the mention in the documentation and also performing better (which makes sense considering the reindexing with both `unshift` & `shift`).

For **queue**s this suggests to use `push` & `shift`, despite the mention in the documentation.