# How to get the last value in multiselect field using PHP

Tags: php, implode

I have a multi-select form feeding from database, if I implode it with comma separated, I will get values like   item1,item2,item3. However, I only want to get the last selected item which is item3 in d  case above. I also tried to explode to split it but didn't work out

this is my code below

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="enrolledterm[]" style="width: 100%;" data-toggle="select2" data-placeholder="Select Terms.." data-allow-clear="true" required="required">
            <option value="<?php echo $term_one_date ?>">Winter Term ends on <?php echo $term_one_date ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $term_two_date ?>">Spring Term ends on <?php echo $term_two_date ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $term_three_date ?>">Summer Term ends on <?php echo $term_three_date ?></option>
                </select>

$enrolled_term = explode(" ", $_POST['enrolled_term']) ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to get the last element of an array without deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687358/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-without-deleting-it)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simplest one, Here we are using [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function.

[**Try this with an example**](https://eval.in/839426)

```
$enrolled_term=end($_POST['enrolled_term']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : to get last selected value (from array)

```
$total_selected = count($_POST['enrolled_term']);
$enrolled_term = $_POST['enrolled_term'][$total_selected-1] ; //last index
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last element of an array, use `array_slice()`:

```
$lastElement = array_values(array_slice($_POST['enrolled_term'], -1))[0];
```

[array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) — Extract a slice of the array

Comment: sorry one more thing, its working well on localhost, but throwing internal server error on cpanel. and my cpanel not recording any error log.

Comment: Is it throwing error at this line? because this code isn;t throwing any error or warning. You can check here: https://3v4l.org/5oXGi

Comment: Yes i can see its not throwing any error from above, and it works well on localhost too, but when i uload online, it throws internal server error, and when i comment it ouit, site reloads fine. Im not sure maybe my server nt supported.

Comment: Hmm, this are PHP functions, no additional installations required. May be, check if `$_POST` is not empty, only than should this code execute.

Comment: I use $enrolled_term=end($_POST['enrolled_term']); and it worked, i guess array_slice is using higer version of php not supported by my server because it works well on localhost. Thanks so much all the same

Comment: That's very strange. this functions are not deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Just get last item in $_POST['enrolled_term'] . Use end() in PHP `end($_POST['enrolled_term'])` or `$_POST['enrolled_term'][count($_POST['enrolled_term']) - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Use count() function to get the last items which equals count-1

```
$terms = explode(" ", $_POST['enrolled_term']) ;
$enrolled_term =$terms[count($terms)-1];
```