# How to only get last value of array in php in shopify

Tags: php, api, curl, shopify

I am creating APP for Shopify and I need the last fulfillment id of an order.

This is my code

```
if($value['fulfillment_status'] == 'fulfilled') {
 foreach($value['fulfillments'] as $id) {
  echo $id['id'].'<br>';
 }
}
```

The output is

```
3549057974422
3555100033174
3557460050070
3560109277334
3560268103830
3560845475990
3561173024918
```

I only want to save or get the last fulfillment id value which is

```
3561173024918
```

How to do this ?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to get the last element of an array without deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687358/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-without-deleting-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [end()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

```
echo end($value['fulfillments'])["id"];
```

Answer (score 3):

The **end** function returns the last value of an array and sets the pointer to the last value.

Based on your output, `end($value['fulfillments'])` would return `3561173024918` as required.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this PHP function : `end($value['fulfillment_status'])` which will give you the last element in the array, your code will be like this :

```php
if($value['fulfillment_status'] == 'fulfilled') {
    echo end($value['fulfillment_status']);`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built-in function for that

```
array_key_last($array);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php