# PHP How to echo certain position of associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

My array looks like this:

```
Array
    ( [myarr] => Array (
                [504] => 2
                [508] => 25
        )
    )
```

Is it possible to echo a certain position of this array? I have tried:

```
echo $_SESSION['myarr'][0][0];
```

I can't seem to get anything to echo back.

EDIT: to be more specific.. Is it possible to echo it based on numeric index?

Comment: What do you want to get? There is no key `0` in `$_SESSION['myarr']`.

Comment: echo $_SESSION['myarr'][504]; returns what?

Comment: There is no key `[0]` Your array contains `$_SESSION['myarr'][504]` and 508

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array_keys()` to get the keys into an array. Then access the 2D array using indexes in the keys array. Not that this is the best way to do this but it is a way to use numeric indexes to solve your problem.

```
$keys = array_keys($_SESSION["myarr"]);
$zero = $_SESSION["myarr"][$keys[0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a regular nested array. You use the index keys just as you normally would:

```
echo $_SESSION['myarr'][504];  //2

echo $_SESSION['myarr'][508];  //25
```

Comment: 504 and 508 are numeric indexes. You can't echo the 0 index or the 1 because they are undefined

Comment: 504 and 508 are the numeric index

Comment: @Norse 504 and 504 _are_ the numeric indices.  If you want to renumber them sequentially from zero use `array_values($_SESSION['myarr'])`

Comment: Those are numeric indexes. If you want them to be 0, 1,2, etc, you need to create a new array with those new keys containing the old values. `array_values()` can do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Get the first element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-first-element-of-array).

The following should work (untested, so no guaranties):

```
echo array_shift(array_values($_SESSION))[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible

```
print $array['myarr'][508]; // 25
```

Answer (score -2):

This is getting ugly.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($myarr as $array) {
    if ($i == 2) echo $array;
    $i++;
}
```