# What is the fastest way to get the first item of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-first-element-of-an-array)

What is the fastest and easiest way to get the first item of an array in php?
I only need the first item of the array saved in a string and the array must not be modified.

Comment: An array saved in a string? Could you give an example of that array?

Comment: @Ikke: I think he meant he wants the first item of the array to be saved in a string. Arrays cannot be saved in strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that this is very optimized:

```
echo reset($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not but try this out

```
$max = 2000;
$array = range(1, 2000);
echo "<pre>";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {
     $item = current($array);
}
echo  microtime(true) - $start  ,PHP_EOL;


$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {
     $item = reset($array);
}
echo  microtime(true) - $start  ,PHP_EOL;


$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {
    $item = $array[0];
}
echo  microtime(true) - $start  ,PHP_EOL;



$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {
    $item = &$array[0];
}
echo  microtime(true) - $start  ,PHP_EOL;


$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {
     $item = array_shift($array);
}
echo  microtime(true) - $start  ,PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
0.03761100769043
0.037437915802002
0.00060200691223145  <--- 2nd Position
0.00056600570678711  <--- 1st Position
0.068138122558594
```

So the fastest is

```
 $item = &$array[0];
```

Comment: But he wants a string, not a reference.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit the reference was just for a benchmark

Comment: Although not always first element would be under [0]

Answer (score 1):

Use `reset`:

```
<?php
$array = Array(0 => "hello", "w" => "orld");
echo reset($array);
// Output: "hello"
?>
```

Note that the array's cursor is set to the beginning of the array when you use this.

### [Live demonstration](http://ideone.com/KCiS8)

(Naturally, you can store the result into a string instead of `echo`ing, but I use `echo` for demonstration purposes.)

Comment: I'm not aware of such function.

Comment: @Veseliq: http://uk.php.net/reset -- now you are!

Comment: You suggested `begin()` before the edit :)

Comment: @Veseliq: What edit?! You are hallucinating...! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
$firstitem = $array[0];
```

Comment: Only works with numeric keys.

Comment: Only works with numeric keys that are in numeric order.

Comment: True, but he did ask for the fastest :P

Comment: The fastest way to fail, perhaps

Answer (score 0):

[`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) does this:

```
$item = reset($array);
```

This will work irrespective of what the keys are, but it will move the array pointer (I 've *never* had a reason to worry about this, but it should be mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is getting the reference, so not string copy is involved:

```
$first = &$array[0];
```

Just make sure you don't modify `$first`, as it will be modified in the array too. If you have to modify it then look for the other answers alternatives.

Comment: But this doesn't store anything into a string.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It just stores the reference, not the contents, that's the reason it's the most efficient.

Comment: It's also the reason that it does not answer the question.