# Return Array Element without Creating Variable

Tags: php, arrays

I feel stupid for asking this cause it seems so basic but it's really bugging me.

I have a method that returns an array with a single element. I just want it to return the element not wrapped in an array. I tried this.

```
return $f->getValue()[0];
```

and it gives an error but if I save it to a variable, it works fine.

```
$v = $f->getValue();
return $v[0];
```

I can't figure it out....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

```
<?php return reset( $f->getValue() ); ?>
```

**Edit:** reset() is probably superior to current() as it also makes sure that the internal pointer is reset, despite it not making much difference if the array only contains one element.

Comment: It's annoying that this requires a workaround... at least they fixed it in 5.4

Answer (score 4):

It's available only since PHP 5.4: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VHOW0o

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do, is called [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88), and is only possible in PHP as of version 5.4 (if you scroll up a few lines in the documentation article I linked to, you'll see it mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know since you are returning an array you only can get an array.  You can instead save the array to a variable in the class (accessible by `$f->myArray`) and then return just the string portion.  Or  the other option is to do what your second example is and return the array and retrieve the string from it.

Comment: I may be wrong though. Why do you want to return an array if you only want the string?

Comment: It's a library... they are cases when it returns arrays of strings

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
         <?php
           return array_shift(array_values($array));
         ?>
```

[Get the first element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-first-element-of-an-array)