# print certain elements of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, echo

I am creating a top-site and I have a question about echoing a certain element of a multidimensional-array. I am using a library called [GameQ](https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ) to ping gaming servers to grab statistics of said server.  I am unable to print the results from certain elements in the array that I specify.

My Code:

```
        <?php

    // Include the main class file
    require '../GameQ.php';

    $gq = new GameQ();
    $gq->addServer(array(
        'id' => '0',
        'type' => 'minecraft',
        'host' => '192.210.238.76:25865',
    ));

    $results = $gq->requestData(); // Returns an array of results

//Below line returns a error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0
    echo "Online: " . $results[0]['numplayers'] . "/" . $results[0]['maxplayers'] . "<br />";

    var_dump($results);

    ?>
```

Array Var dump:

```
        array (size=1)
  '192.210.238.76:25865' => 
    array (size=17)
      'hostname' => string 'A Whole Other Level' (length=19)
      'gametype' => string 'SMP' (length=3)
      'game_id' => string 'MINECRAFT' (length=9)
      'version' => string '1.6.4' (length=5)
      'plugins' => string 'CraftBukkit on Bukkit 1.6.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT' (length=41)
      'map' => string 'Build' (length=5)
      'numplayers' => string '6' (length=1)
      'maxplayers' => string '30' (length=2)
      'hostport' => string '25865' (length=5)
      'hostip' => string '192.210.238.76' (length=14)
      'players' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          3 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          4 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          5 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      'gq_online' => boolean true
      'gq_address' => string '192.210.238.76' (length=14)
      'gq_port' => string '25865' (length=5)
      'gq_protocol' => string 'gamespy3' (length=8)
      'gq_type' => string 'minecraft' (length=9)
      'gq_transport' => string 'udp' (length=3)
```

I have reviewed the manual for array's at [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  I would appreciate anyone's help on this topic.  I know I am missing something.  I have tried to search for the answer first, before registering to ask this question.  I would think searching for the results would be faster than waiting on someone to help me with the answer.  Thank you for your patients and your understanding. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key 0 does not exist in the array,try with

```
$results['192.210.238.76:25865']['numplayers']
```

**EDIT**

As this is probably variable, you can fetch the first element of an array without modifying the array this way:

```
$firstValue = array_shift(array_values($results)); //the array which is the first value

$numplayers = $firstValue['numplayers'];
```

Line found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3771228/1935128)

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed it right up. I tried adding the IP before, but forgot the ' and '.  Thanks for helping me!