# PHP implode explode first and last array value

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

i'm still a freshman on PHP.
So i have a variable called 'full name' and i was trying to explode and implode the first and the last variable value.

```
$fullname='Andre Filipe da Costa Ferreira';
$namepieces=explode('', $fullname);
$flname=implode('', namepieces[0], namepieces[lastvar]);
echo "Welcome".$flname;
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me! Thanks :D

Comment: You're missing the `$` in front of `namepieces` on line 3; otherwise - what is the issue that you're having? Do you get an error message? A blank screen? The wrong data?

Comment: yes, please clarify with an example: what _would_ input look like, what _should_ output be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This with name pieces separated with a space, and works with a single name piece like Andre:

```
<?php
$fullname = 'Andre Filipe da Costa Ferreira';
$namepieces = explode(' ', $fullname);
$n = count($namepieces);
if($n > 1) {
  $flname = implode(' ', array($namepieces[0], $namepieces[$n-1]));
} else {
  $flname = $namepieces[0];
}
echo "Welcome " . $flname;
//
?>
```

This gets:

```
Welcome Andre Ferreira
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$names = explode(" ", "Andre Filipe da Costa Ferreira");
printf("Welcome %s %s", current($names), end($names));
```

where `current()` gets its first element, and `end()` last one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `end($namepieces);` which returns the value of the last element or FALSE for empty array.Also your are missing $ before namepieces

```
$flname=implode('', $namepieces[0], end($namepieces));
```

[**end()**](https://www.php.net/end)

Another example taken from php.net for getting first and last element from array

```
$items = array( 'one', 'two', 'three' );
$lastItem = end( $items ); // three
$current = current( $items ); // one
```

Comment: @ThomWiggers for OP's problem it suits best i have shown him both ways either using index 0 or current()

Comment: **`current()` isn't a way to get index 0**: `current()` is a way to get the current element of an array when walking through it using an iterator/`next()`/`prev()`. That it happens to be index 0 at first isn't a reason to use `current()` for this.

Comment: Why is it better than using `[0]`?

Comment: @ThomWiggers because its php's built-in function

Comment: Also OP might as well use `reset()` then which guaranteed returns the first element (and resets the pointer). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-first-element-of-an-array.

Comment: I gave you a `-1` since I think your "because it's a built-in function" argument is invalid when compared to a language construct.

Comment: @ThomWiggers i don't want to mess arround with this i have others things to do

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$fullname = 'Andre Filipe da Costa Ferreira';
$namepieces = explode(' ', $fullname);
$flname = implode(' ', array($namepieces[0], $namepieces[count($namepieces)-1]));
echo "Welcome " . $flname;
//
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its beter way I guess

```
<?php
$fullname = 'Andre Filipe da Costa Ferreira';
$namepieces = explode(' ', $fullname);
$n = count($namepieces);
$n > 0 ? $flname = implode(' ', array($namepieces[0], $namepieces[$n-1])) : $flname = $namepieces[0];
echo "Welcome " . $flname;
//
?>
```