# retrieve from array, simple php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this:

```
print_r($response["member"]);
```

I need to retrieve `name` under `levels`, it's at the bottom, how should I write it:
I thought of  `$response["member"][0]["Sequential"]["levels"]...`? Also this number under levels wont be always the same.

Thank you!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [UserInfo] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [caps] => Array
                        (
                            [administrator] => 1
                        )

                    [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
                    [roles] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => administrator
                        )

                    [allcaps] => Array
                        (
                            [switch_themes] => 1
                            [edit_themes] => 1
                            [activate_plugins] => 1
                            [edit_plugins] => 1
                            [edit_users] => 1
                            [edit_files] => 1
                            [manage_options] => 1
                            [moderate_comments] => 1
                            [manage_categories] => 1
                            [manage_links] => 1
                            [upload_files] => 1
                            [import] => 1
                            [unfiltered_html] => 1
                            [edit_posts] => 1
                            [edit_others_posts] => 1
                            [edit_published_posts] => 1
                            [publish_posts] => 1
                            [edit_pages] => 1
                            [read] => 1
                            [level_10] => 1
                            [level_9] => 1
                            [level_8] => 1
                            [level_7] => 1
                            [level_6] => 1
                            [level_5] => 1
                            [level_4] => 1
                            [level_3] => 1
                            [level_2] => 1
                            [level_1] => 1
                            [level_0] => 1
                            [edit_others_pages] => 1
                            [edit_published_pages] => 1
                            [publish_pages] => 1
                            [delete_pages] => 1
                            [delete_others_pages] => 1
                            [delete_published_pages] => 1
                            [delete_posts] => 1
                            [delete_others_posts] => 1
                            [delete_published_posts] => 1
                            [delete_private_posts] => 1
                            [edit_private_posts] => 1
                            [read_private_posts] => 1
                            [delete_private_pages] => 1
                            [edit_private_pages] => 1
                            [read_private_pages] => 1
                            [delete_users] => 1
                            [create_users] => 1
                            [unfiltered_upload] => 1
                            [edit_dashboard] => 1
                            [update_plugins] => 1
                            [delete_plugins] => 1
                            [install_plugins] => 1
                            [update_themes] => 1
                            [install_themes] => 1
                            [update_core] => 1
                            [list_users] => 1
                            [remove_users] => 1
                            [add_users] => 1
                            [promote_users] => 1
                            [edit_theme_options] => 1
                            [delete_themes] => 1
                            [export] => 1
                            [administrator] => 1
                        )

                    [filter] => 
                    [user_login] => admin
                    [user_nicename] => admin
                    [user_email] => goranefbl@gmail.com
                    [user_url] => 
                    [user_registered] => 2014-01-29 10:57:09
                    [user_activation_key] => 
                    [user_status] => 0
                    [display_name] => admin
                    [wlm_feed_url] => http://pialarson.com/excel/feed/?wpmfeedkey=1;2e7e48ca65d94e5f0ec1baae46e4972c
                    [wpm_login_date] => 1392155735
                    [wpm_login_ip] => 62.68.119.252
                )

            [Sequential] => 
            [Levels] => Array
                (
                    [1391447566] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Level_ID] => 1391447566
                            [Name] => Team Membership
                            [Cancelled] => 
                            [CancelDate] => 
                            [Pending] => 
                            [UnConfirmed] => 
                            [Expired] => 
                            [ExpiryDate] => 1393866766
                            [SequentialCancelled] => 
                            [Active] => 1
                            [Status] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Active
                                )

                            [Timestamp] => 1391447566
                            [TxnID] => WL-1-1391447566
                        )

                )

            [PayPerPosts] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Sequential doesn't have anything in it, try doing just Levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer might be to use `array_walk_recursive` by following the official documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

```
<?php

$properties = new stdClass();
$properties->names = [];
function extractNames($levels, $key, $properties) {
    if (
        is_object($levels) &&
        array_key_exists('Name', get_object_vars($levels)) &&
        array_key_exists('Level_ID', get_object_vars($levels))
    ) {
        $properties->names[] = $levels->Name;
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($response, 'extractNames', $properties);
echo print_r($properties, true);
```

Comment: I see, so if i have multiple names, it will add them to array. This is what i was looking for,thanks!

Comment: There might be a reference missing somewhere (or perhaps replace $names array by another standard object such as `$names = new StdClass();` would help even more)... I'm trying to prove it working by building a reference array but you have the main idea!

Comment: hmm i am getting  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: it is php version 5.2.17

Comment: You might want to extract the function elsewhere if your version of PHP doesn't support closures and pass the function to array_walk_recursive as a callable like `array('function_name')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47272/discussion-between-thierry-marianne-and-goran-jakovljevic)

Comment: Again big thanks Thierry, ill go with first one for now

Comment: Well noted! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $nameInFirstLevelsElement = current($response["member"][0]["levels"])->Name
?>
```

This should work to retrieve the `Name` from the first `levels` element.

Answer (score 1):

That empty space next to "Sequential" means it doesn't have a value. So that's not the one you're looking for.

Furthermore, one of those levels indicates "stdClass object", which means you can access its members via the `->` operator.

Let's strip away everything that doesn't matter for a minute. I think it'll help you understand the data structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Levels] => Array
                (
                    [1391447566] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Level_ID] => 1391447566
                            [Name] => Team Membership
                        )
                )
        )

)
```

So this will work:

```
$object = $response["member"][0]["Levels"][1391447566];
$name = $object->Name;
```

**Edit**

If the index of Levels changes every time, then pull it apart a little bit more...

```
$levels = $response["member"][0]["Levels"];
$firstLevel = array_shift(array_values($levels));
$name = $firstLevel->Name;
```

See here for a good answer on getting the first element out of the `$levels` array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3771228/266374

Comment: Aha, this number "1391447566" will be diffrent every time, is it possible to somehow skip it or how would we do then ?

Comment: `array_shift(array_values($levels))` -> why not simply `current($levels)`?

Comment: @Flixer In case an associative array is returned. I don't know anything about this API, so I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: hey @ThomasKelley if i want to retrieve not one but all levels, how would it look like ?

Answer (score 1):

If the number under the 'Levels' array won't be the same, you can use a foreach to pull out the 'Name' information.

```
foreach ($response[0]['Levels'] AS $level_key => $level_val) {
    $level_name = $level_key->Name;
}

echo 'Name: '.$level_name;
```

If there is only going to be one element, then it will grab it.  If there are multiple numbers under 'Levels', then it will loop through them and assign each one to '$level_name', overwriting any previous assignments.  In other words, only the last one it finds will be captured.

EDIT:
In the example, I mistakenly tried to grab the `Name` from the `$key` instead of the `$val`.  This is the correct method:

```
foreach ($response[0]['Levels'] AS $level_key => $level_val) {
    $level_name = $level_val->Name;
}

echo 'Name: '.$level_name;
```

[Here is a demo of the working code](http://ideone.com/R6kfx8)

Comment: Well, you're correct.  I have a typo in my code.  You should be getting the `Name` from the `val`, not the `key`.  I will make an update in my post with the correct syntax.