# Showing the first element in an foreach array in HTML

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $category['transactions']. It stores data as follow:

```
ID   Name  Phone
1   Test   Test2
2   Test3  Test4
```

It's because I use the same array for different purpose, at one of the scenario is to show only the first record in this array. I don't what to change the coding in php nor creating a different parameter. What can I improve based on the following coding in html to get the first record only in this array?

```
                    <?php foreach($category['transactions'] as $transaction) { ?>
                            <div><?php echo $transaction['id']; ?></div>
                            <div><?php echo $transaction['name']; ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-first-element-of-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your code with.

```
<?php $firstRow=reset($category['transactions']);
    echo '<div>',$firstRow['id'],'</div>';
    echo '<div>',$firstRow['name'],'</div>';
?>
```

You don't need to iterate through the array to get the first element.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the foreach to get the first element.  Just use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$first = array_values($category['transactions')[0]
```

Comment: And you don't even need to copy the complete array, just use [`reset()`](http://www.php.net/reset).

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen that before.  Thanks.

Comment: I've added some html code. Would you please base on my example and tell where I should paste your code?

Comment: @user2699714 Try doing the anwser below. Which is the same thing that Markus Malkusch has said.

Comment: @user2699714 Just place the div tags right around `<?php echo array_values($category['transactions')[0] ?>` and remove the foreach loop or put this before it.

Comment: @MONZTAAA ICIC. So how do I reset() based on my code?

Comment: @user2699714 As Anonymous mentioned just put the divs around the code. I edited my answer.

Comment: @user2699714 check my answer for reset solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

`<?php 
    foreach($category['transactions'] as $transaction)
    { 
      echo $transaction['id'];
      break;
    }
?>`

and **no need to use multiple php tags**...

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch .. Ohh yeah.. In hurry I put that `round brackets` let me edit my answer..Thanks..