# PHP Array if has more than X values, return last Y values

Tags: php, arrays

I have very simple question about PHP. (*Please* don't -1 first.)

Imagine we have this array :

```
Array {
[1] => Hi
[3] => Hey
[5] => You
[9] => hello
[13] => yes
[66] => Test
[86] => Test2
[96] => Test3
}
```

(it is not SORTed).

So , I want 2 things :

1. First, find how many values are in this array (in this one, it is **8**);
2. Second, IF it has more than **5** Values, Then Just return 5 First values (as i said it's not sorted in array-numbers , SO , I just want to return 5 First values )

How can we do it in PHP ?

(( I am so sorry Because i am SO beginner and can't find solution in other questions ))

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number of elements: [count()](http://php.net/count)

```
$n = count($array);
```

First 5 elements: [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice)

```
$new_array = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Of course, `array_slice` doesn't care if the array is smaller than five, it just returns the slice *up to five*. The question isn't clear what behavior OP wants when the array is smaller than five.

Comment: I think the whole array

Answer (score 4):

To count the elements you can use `count()`. To get only the first five values you can use [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
if(count($array) > 5) {
    $array = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the `array_slice` returns the first values if the array is not sorted  ?

Comment: It returns the elements based on offset and length (2nd and 3rd parameter). So it starts at the offset 0 (beginning) and returns 5 elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use count to count the number of arrays.

**Like this:**

```
$result = count($array);// if array  is variable
```

**and array_slice will be a better idea**

```
array_slice($array, 0, 5)
```

**for more detail see this answer:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3771228/3151394

Comment: You do know what array_shift() does? It makes absolutely no sense to use it here.

Comment: array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. this will solve number difference.

Comment: No it won't. Since you're using it wrong and he wants the first 5 elements and not the five last elements. And you'd even have to make a loop to make it dynamic.

Comment: Oh sorry I was look somewhere else! I have edited my answer. thanks @CharlotteDunois