# Checking the first element of array, regardless of array indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have a need to check if the elements in an `array` are `objects` or something else. So far I did it like this:

```
if((is_object($myArray[0]))) { ... }
```

However, on occasion situations dictate that the input `array` does not have indexes that start with zero (or aren't even `numeric`), therefore asking for `$myArray[0]` will generate a `Notice`, but will also return the wrong result in my condition if the first array element actually is an `object` (but under another index).

The only way I can think of doing here is a `foreach` loop where I would break out of it right on the first go.

```
foreach($myArray as $element) {
   $areObjects = (is_object($element));
   break;
}
if(($areObjects)) { ... }
```

But I am wondering if there is a faster code than this, because a `foreach` loop seems unnecessary here.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `reset()` function to get first index data from array

```
if(is_object(reset($myArray))){
 //do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
reset($myArray);
$firstElement = current($myArray);
```

current gets the element in the current index, therefore you should reset the pointer of the array to the first element using reset

http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Comment: `Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given`

Answer (score 0):

You could get an array of keys and get the first one:

```
$keys = array_keys($myArray);
if((is_object($myArray[$keys[0]]))) { ... }
```