# MongoDB: get value from field in founded record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm a newbie in MongoDB.
I use MongoDB 6.0.3 and MongoDB Compass 1.34.2.

I have a DB with data:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "attr": [
        {"name": "Some Name 1", "val": "Some value"},
        {"name": "Some Name 2", "val": "blabla"},
        {
            "name": "Need Find",
            "val": "I Need This Value"
        },
        {"name": "Nevermind", "val": "3.14"}
    ]
},
{
    "id": 33333,
    "attr": [
        {"name": "Some Name 1", "val": "Some value"},
        {"name": "Some Name 2", "val": "blabla"},
        {
            "name": "Need Find",
            "val": "I Need This Value but ID is not match"
        },
        {"name": "Nevermind",   "val": "3.14"}
    ]
}
```

So I find record by query:

```
db.myTable.find({'id' : '123', 'attr' : { $elemMath : {'name' : 'Need Find'}} })
```

And this returns a complete record.

How I can return only the field with the value (or value only) of field "val"?

Example what I need:

```
"val": "I Need This Value"
```

or:

```
"I Need This Value"
```

I need to return by query only one field-value or value of a field of a founded record.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Find all matched array element from single document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818179/mongodb-find-all-matched-array-element-from-single-document)

Comment: no, it doesn't.
I need get value from definitely field on result, for this data structure after query it's a attr.2.val from record id = 123.

Comment: Have you tried using aggregation with $match and $project

Comment: not yet! thx for suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    "id": 1,
    "attr.name": "Need Find"
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$attr"
},
{
  $match: {
    "attr.name": "Need Find"
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "attr.val": 1
  }
})
```