# How to get first element from a sub array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to get the first element from a subarray. The data needed in my result collection looks like this:

```
#attributes:array:11 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "Eerst nieuwsbericht voor Jochen"
    "content" => "<p>Dit is een test</p>\n"
    "tags" => ""
    "images" => "[2,3,4,1]"
    "social_media" => ""
    "publish_date" => "2015-08-27 01:40:17"
    "created_at" => "2015-08-27 13:40:17"
    "updated_at" => "2015-08-27 13:40:17"
    "slug" => "eerst-nieuwsbericht-voor-jochen"
    "files" => array:4 [▼
        2 => array:11 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "parent_id" => 0
            "type" => "file"
            "path" => "/uploads/flyfish"
            "name" => "05-vogelkers1-E2.jpg"
            "file_type" => "jpg"
            "size" => 162936
            "width" => 1024
            "height" => 768
            "created_at" => Carbon {#368 ▶}
            "updated_at" => Carbon {#338 ▶}
          ]
      3 => array:11 [▶]
      4 => array:11 [▶]
      1 => array:11 [▶]
    ]
]
```

I want to get the 'name' from the first element in the sub array 'files'. Is there a shorthand notation to do so?

I can get to my needed result with

```
$newsDetail->files[2]['name']
```

But then I need to know that key 2 is actually the first key in the array 'files'.

Comment: which language / platform it is?

Comment: @tomsoft I am working in php. It's a Laravel-collection I am getting back.

Comment: add a language tag. At 144 reputation, one shouldn't have to tell you that.

Comment: Sure, and if it's php, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array

Comment: @MarcusMüller true that. Had 2 hours sleep tonight causing brain malfunction today

Answer (score 0):

> [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and
>   returns the value of the first array element.

So i believe in your case:

```
var_dump(reset($newsDetail->files)['name'])
```

Comment: same here: Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Jvd\Modules\News\Models\News has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
current($newsDetail['files']);
```

Comment: I am getting: Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Jvd\Modules\News\Models\News has no effect