# get first element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Lets assume, the return value of an search-fuction is something like this

```
// If only one record is found
$value = [
  'records' => [
    'record' => ['some', 'Important', 'Information']
  ]
]

// If multiple records are found
$value = [
  'records' => [
    'record' => [
       0 => ['some', 'important', 'information'],
       1 => ['some', 'information', 'I dont care']
    ]
  ]
]
```

what woul'd be the best way to get the important information (in case of multiple records, it is always the first one)?

Should I check something like

```
if (array_values($value['record']['records'])[0] == 0){//do something};
```

But I guess, there is a way more elegant solution.

Edit:
And btw, this is not realy a duplicate of the refered question which only covers the multiple records.

Comment: Right @Uchiha and explain your query in detail. Not getting exactly what you want.

Comment: return value should be the ['some', 'important', 'infomation'].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the first element of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array)

Comment: Ok, getting now. You can check it like this `if(is_array($value['records']['record'][0])) { $new_array=$value['records']['record'])[0]; } else { $new_array=$value['records']['record']; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first element of an array, you should use `reset`. This function sets the pointer to the first element and returns it.

```
$firstValue = reset($value['record']['records']);
```

Edit.. after reading your question again, it seems, you dont want the first element.
You rather want this

```
if (isset($value['record']['records'][0]) && is_array($value['record']['records'][0])) {
    // multiple return values
} else {
    // single return value
}
```

Doing this is kind of error proun and i wouldn't suggest that one function returns different kinds of array structures.

Comment: Ok, that's what I did. I thought there might be a more fancy solution :)

Answer (score 0):

check like this..

```
if(is_array($value['records']['record'][0])) {
    // multiple records
} else {
    // single record
}
```