# access first element of array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got something but still it isn't working like I want it to work.

I've got an array

```
    $values = array(
    $aV=>$aP, 
    $bV=>$bP, 
    $cV=>$cP, 
    $dV=>$dP
);
```

then I `sort` it like this `    arsort($values);

the result is `Array ( [geel] => 28 [groen] => 20 [rood] => 20 [blauw] => 12 )`

Now I want to acces the first / second / tird / fourth element to pass it on 
So I want `$values[0]` to be the first element. In this case `Geel 28`. But if I try to echo `$values[0]` it says  `Undefined offset: 0` (same with 1/2/3 etc). Obviously because I've got no `[0]` set but how can I set `[0]` to the first element in the array (which is different each time. the value `geel` isn't always `[0]` but I need the first element (with the lowest number) to be `[0]` so I can echo `$values[0]` to be the first element of the array with the lowest number

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array)

Comment: your index is [geel] not [0].

Comment: `$values = array_values($values)`

Comment: For what purpose must you directly access a specific element? How about *looping* over all elements in turn? `foreach ($values as $key => $value) ..`

Comment: But I also need the name (geel/ groen etc) @splash58

Comment: use `array_keys($values)`

Comment: @FrayneKonok array_keys($values) returns the same `array` as the regular `print_r($values)`

Comment: nope, It returns the keys as value.

Comment: Thanks @FrayneKonok I used that one together wit the comment of splash58 and it SEEMS to work. I'm gonna try it out. Thanks for the help

Comment: When you say you want the _first,second third and last_ does that mean you have an array that is larger that 4 occurances or do you mean you want all the occurances and the array in question is only 4 occurances

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the index and the value of your array, then a foreach loop can do that for you

```
$values = array($aV=>$aP,  $bV=>$bP,  $cV=>$cP, $dV=>$dP );

foreach ( $values as $idx => $val ) {
    echo "Index is $idx and value is $val";
}
```

With this array you gave as an example

```
Array ( [geel] => 28 [groen] => 20 [rood] => 20 [blauw] => 12 )
```

the output would be

```
Index is geel and value is 28
Index is groen and value is 20
Index is rood and value is 20
Index is blauw and value is 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Because array key has been set as geel, groen..you can not access like $values[0],$values[1].

You must access like:

First element: `$values['geel']`
Second element: `$values['groen']` etc....

Comment: I know. I updated my question. But how can I acces the first element of the array as `[0]`. because 'geel' 'groen' etc aren't always in the same position of the array. I need to call the first element , second etc wich are all different everytime

Comment: simply go with #splash58 in your post comment

Answer (score 0):

For accessing both values and keys as numeric index you need to use `array_values` and `array_keys`

**Array:**

```
$values = array(
    $aV=>$aP, 
    $bV=>$bP, 
    $cV=>$cP, 
    $dV=>$dP
);
```

For the values:

```
$new_values = array_values($values);
```

Result:

`array($aP, $bP, $cP, $dP);`

For the keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($values);
```

Result:

`array($aV, $bV, $cV, $dV);`

Now you can access both the array as numeric keys like: `$keys[0]` or `$new_values[0]` and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the "arrow" indicator to make your arrays, you're probably looking to do this:

```
$values = array(
    $aV . ' ' . $aP,
    $bV . ' ' . $bP,
    $cV . ' ' . $cP,
    $dV . ' ' . $dP,
);
```

What you're currently doing is creating an array that looks like this

```
[
    'Geel' => 28
    // etc.
]
```

If you really just wanted to get the value of the first element you could use `array_shift`

Comment: I need to get the first, second, third and last element. Everytime