# PHP adressing the first key in an array that changes

Tags: php, arrays

For example, lets say I have an array that looks liked

```
$stuff = array('random_string_1' => 'random_value_1','random_string_2' => 'random_value_2');
```

and then I call  the asort() function and it changes the array around. How do I get the new first string without knowing what it actually is?

Comment: The answer to this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array

Comment: This, `echo $stuff[key($stuff)];`. Here's the doc, [http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the first value of the array you can use **[reset](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)**

```
reset($stuff);
```

If you want to also get the key use **[key](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)**

```
key($stuff);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the first value, do it like this:

```
$stuff = array('random_string_1' => 'random_value_1','random_string_2' => 'random_value_2');

$values = array_values($stuff); // this is a consequential array with values in the order of the original array

var_dump($values[0]); // get first value..
var_dump($values[1]); // get second value..
```