# suppress key from an array search and get the next key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to suppress a key from a multidimensional array and get the next occurrence key.

```
$array_example = array(

    'default_group' => 'styling',

    'general'   => esc_html__('General', THEMETEXTDOMAIN),

    // User can enter it here
    // 'default_group' => 'styling',

    'styling'   => esc_html__('Styling', THEMETEXTDOMAIN),

    // 'default_group' => 'styling',

    'animate'   => esc_html__('Animate', THEMETEXTDOMAIN),
)
```

[default_group] key is a fixed key but it might be at any position.

I need to get the next key if the [default_group] key not exist or it has an empty value.

```
if( array_key_exists( 'default_group', $array_example ) && !empty( $array_example['default_group'] ) ) {

     $col_group_default = sanitize_text_field( $array_example['default_group'] );

} else {

     // Here I want to get the key BUT NOT [default_group]                                

}
```

Comment: If you aren't using the array later on, why not just `unset()` it after assigning it to `$col_group_default`?

Comment: I need the full array after this

Comment: In the `else { ...` are you looping the array to get the other keys?

Comment: In this instance, would you be wanting to get `'general'` next?

Comment: Or maybe [just the first item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array)?

Comment: I need to get the key [general] 'cause it's the first key if avoid [default_group]

Answer (score 0):

```
$choice = '';
$default = array_search('default_group', array_keys($array_example));

if ( $default && !empty($array_example[ $default ]) ) {
  $choice = $array_example[ $default ];
} else {
  $choice = isset($array_example[ $default + 1]) ? $array_example[ $default + 1] : $array_example[0];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackov.... oh wait, you're here long enough to know that "here are teh codez" answers are not really helpful. Please try to explain how and why the code you posted solves OPs problem.

Comment: Extended code to also include the scenario of `$default` being empty last element, which makes `$default+1` invalid.

Comment: @LJᛃ  I think you are wrong. I am using the exact logic the Op is already using, just different functions. Functions with a pretty much selfexplaining name. What you describe would be right if I just threw some code at a topic lik this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529018/combing-value-of-same-elements, which I do not.