# Combing value of same elements

Tags: php

[This is data that is coming from previous page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP5aC.png)

Now I want to show my data like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung
            [serial] => fsa
            [unit_price] => 8800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => N100
            [serial] => tr , qw , re
            [unit_price] => 8480
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => N98
            [serial] => n9t
            [unit_price] => 7980
        )

)
```

*Means Combing values of same element N100*

Comment: what have you tried to achieve this? Where's the problem?

Comment: I have different serials with different item names
one item can have more than 1 Serials so I wanna combine serials of same item name

Comment: You would get a lot of solutions if you searched, better tried also.

Comment: I searched but didn't find solution according to my requirement

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $data = array();
        foreach($d as $key => $value) {
            if(key_exists($value["name"], $data)) {
                $d = $data[$value["name"]];
                $d["serial"] .= $value["serial"] . ", ";
                $data[$value["name"]] = $d;
            }
            else {
                $data[$value["name"]] = array( "name" => $value["name"], "serial" => $value["serial"]. ", ", "unit_price" => $value["unit_price"] );
            }
        }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be help you

```
$arr1=array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    unset($arr[$key]);
    if(!array_key_exists($value['name'],$arr1)){
        foreach($arr as $key1=>$value1){
        if($value['name']==$value1['name']){
            $value['serial'] =$value['serial'].",".$value1['serial'];
        }
    }
    $arr1[$value['name']]=$value;

    }   
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr1);
```