# What is the best way to ensure all key value pairs exist in an PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I want to avoid doing multiple conditionals per key value - a case in which , say, "$first_node['logo'];" is not avalable

```
        foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
         // I want to avoid conditional here for each node


         $first_node         = $value[0];
         $logo             = $first_node['logo'];
         $name            = $first_node['name'];
         break;
        }
```

Comment: Why would you put it in a loop and then break after the first iteration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Use isset.

```
$logo = isset($first_node['logo']) ? $first_node['logo']:null;
```

Comment: The are more values, how do I do it in one conditional for all - in this case for name and logo plus any others

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple, if you're using >= PHP7 use the coalesce operator

```
$name = $first_node['name'] ?? null;
```

If you're using an older version

```
$name = isset($first_node['name']) ? $first_node['name'] : null;
```

Comment: The second one will actually produce undefined index warnings if it's not set.

Comment: The are more values, how do I do it in one conditional for all - in this case for name and logo plus any others

Comment: @php_needs You would have to keep an array of all the possible variable keys. Loop through the array and check if the key exists in first_node, if now set it to null.