# How to get the value in a key-value pair in a complex array?

Tags: php

I have an array coming into my PHP function that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [BULD-FAX] => 5.00
)
```

The string **BULD-FAX** is dynamic and not known until runtime. I'm simply trying to get the dollar value, which in this case is **5.00**.

Here's my code:

```
$productName = key($myArray);
$amount =  $myArray[$productName]->{0};
```

`$productName` evaluates to **BULD-FAX** as expected. But `$amount` is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use `reset($array);` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array

Comment: `array_values($myArray)[0]` would be fine too.

Comment: Or `array_shift` but this modifies the array

Comment: Niet, that worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a better way to do it, but you could do a loop that would only execute one time (in the case of your example).  It would look like this:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $productName = $key;
    $amount =  $value;
//do something here with the values if there are more than one item in the array
}
```