# PHP - Get first and last key and value from array

Tags: php, arrays

From a given array (eg: `$_SERVER`), I need to get the first and last key and value. I was trying use array_shift to get first value and key but what I get is value.

Here is the `$_SERVER` array:

```
print_r($_SERVER, true))
```

And I tried with:

```
echo array_shift($_SERVER);
```

Comment: _Here is the $_SERVER array_ Is it? I see no array!!

Comment: Use array_keys function to get all the keys in array and then use array_shift. Similarly array_values for all the values in array.

Comment: Why would this ever be useful? Is that array ever guaranteed to be a particular order?

Comment: @Mati Urbaniak, did you try with `array_slice()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate out keys and values in separate arrays, and extract first and last from them:

```
// Get all the keys in the array
$all_keys = array_keys($_SERVER);

// Get all the values in the array
$all_values = array_values($_SERVER);

// first key and value
$first_key = array_shift($all_keys);
$first_value = array_shift($all_values);

// last key and value (we dont care about the pointer for the temp created arrays)
$last_key = end($all_keys);
$last_value = end($all_values);

/* you can use reset function after end function call 
   if you worry about the pointer */
```

Comment: Strange to see downvotes. Any explanation guys ? would be helpful !

Comment: Aside from the higher memory usage your solution is just as good as any other. It's a tiny amount of data in this case, but things might get iffy if the array contains a million items. That might explain the downvotes.

Comment: Thanks @Christian !

Answer (score 6):

With PHP >= 7.3 you can get it fast, without modification of the array and without creating array copies:

```
$first_key = array_key_first($_SERVER);
$first_value = $_SERVER[$first_key];

$last_key = array_key_last($_SERVER);
$last_value = $_SERVER[$last_key];
```

See [array_key_first](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) and [array_key_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php).

Comment: Does a foreach loop cause array copies? This is an interesting solution, didn't know these functions were implemented.

Comment: `foreach` doesn't create array copies, but it does modify the array pointer. It doesn't matter in _most_ situations, but still

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want the value, or the key. This is about as efficient as it gets, if memory usage is important.

If you want the key, use array_keys. If you want the value, just refer to it with the key you got from array_keys.

```
$count = count($_SERVER);
if ($count > 0) {
  $keys = array_keys($_SERVER);
  $firstKey = $keys[0];
  $lastKey = $keys[$count - 1];
  $firstValue = $array[$firstKey];
  $lastValue = $array[$lastKey];
}
```

You can't use `$count - 1` or 0 to get the first or last value in keyed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a foreach loop, and break out after the first one:

```
foreach ( $_SERVER as $key => $value ) {
    //Do stuff with $key and $value
    break;
}
```

Plenty of other methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array). You can pick and choose your favorite flavor there.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$server = $_SERVER;
echo array_shift(array_values($server));
echo array_shift(array_keys($server));
```

reversed:

```
$reversed = array_reverse($server);
echo array_shift(array_values($reversed));
echo array_shift(array_keys($reversed));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will do the trick for you.

```
<?php
$a = array_slice($_SERVER, 0, 1);
$b = array_slice($_SERVER, -1, 1, true);
//print_r($_SERVER);
print_r($a);
print_r($b);

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [TERM] => xterm )
Array ( [argc] => 1 )
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/GhoFm