# get value within object in an array

Tags: php, arrays, object, prestashop

I have an array, containing an object. I need the value of a property of the first object but somehow I get an empty value.

My array `$params` (from print_r) looks like this:

```
Array
(
[newOrderStatus] => OrderState Object
    (
        [name] => Canceled
        [template] => order_canceled
        [send_email] => 1
        ...
```

Cut off here, there are two more objects in this array.

Now if I do: `echo $params[0]->name` I get an empty result.

Also tried `print_r($params[0], true);`, empty result.

Also tried, empty result:

```
$status = $params[0];
echo $status->name;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `0` index in `$params`. The only index I can see is `newOrderStatus`.

Comment: Try `$params['newOrderStatus']->name`

Comment: Also duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access object as following

```
$params['newOrderStatus'];
```

In above object you will have all child objects so you can access them by following

```
$params['newOrderStatus']->name;
$params['newOrderStatus']->template;
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I thought I had tried this also, but I was probably lost in trying to much.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you said your array looks like this :

```
Array
(
  [newOrderStatus] => OrderState Object
  (
    [name] => Canceled
    [template] => order_canceled
    [send_email] => 1
    ...
```

So there is no `$param[0]`, you should do `$param['newOrderStatus']` and then get what you want : `$param['newOrderStatus']->name`

Answer (score 1):

Your array `$params` has a key called `newOrderStatus` which has the object as a value you are looking for.

Looking at your example, there is value for index 0.

To get the value of the name property, you could use:

`$params['newOrderStatus']->name`

Answer (score 0):

You can type cast it to an array like this:

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```