# How to echo the first key value of an associative array without knowing the name of the key

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

`print_r` of an array gives me this output:

```
Array (
    [id-1.txt] => uploads/id-1.jpg
    [id-2.txt] => uploads/id-2.jpg
    [id-3.txt] => uploads/id-3.jpg
)
```

How can i echo always the first key value ( so `uploads/id-1.jpg` in this case) without knowing the name of the key? Because the name of the keys are changing everytime...

So: catch always the first value which belongs to the first key, whatever the name of the key is...

Comment: Reading the question OP wants the first value, not the literal first key.

Comment: This is probably a more apt dupe, but it's very noisy!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$data =
[
    'id-1.txt' => 'uploads/id-1.jpg',
    'id-2.txt' => 'uploads/id-2.jpg',
    'id-3.txt' => 'uploads/id-3.jpg'
];

$copy = $data;

echo reset($copy);
unset($copy);
```

Output:

```
uploads/id-1.jpg
```

Here using a copy for no side effects.

Comment: `current($copy)` will do if it's a fresh copy.

Comment: No, when you copy the array you'll copy the pointer.  So reset is a better choice here.