# Nested Array with Dynamic Key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have dynamic file which everytime i upload a file, its name depend on filename
so jsonobj is example,

How can i echo $obj["FILENAME"] everytime the file change? I need a dynamic code

I try make echo $obj[0]["url"];
But it wont work,

```
$jsonobj = '{"File.png":{"name":"File.png","url":"www.example.com/File.png"}}';
$obj = (json_decode($jsonobj,true));
echo $obj["File.png"]["url"];
```

Comment: Why do you use the file name as a key if it's dynamic? Are you always going to have just one file inside that JSON?

Comment: To understand the data structure just do a simple `print_r($obj)` although as you have converted it to an array it would be better to call that `$arr` instead of `$obj`

Comment: A simple `echo $obj['File.png']['name'];` would work, but as @El_Vanja says, using the filename as the key makes this structure very unhelpful

Comment: Okay i tell u whole process. Im using woocommerce so i need to hook to API,
So when i echo my variable such as $jsonobj it will show like that, so i need want to use cURL file, curl file need a url for uploaded image, so that why i to use dynamic.

I dont know if got better solution
to transfer $jsonobj to new CURLFILE

'Images' => new CURLFILE('www.example.com/File.png'),

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the first element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

As your filename changes, the first key changes.

So first retrieve that key (`File.png`), then you can use it to output the content:

```
reset($obj);       // set pointer to first key
$key = key($obj);  // get first key (File.png)

$url = $obj[ $key ][ 'url' ];
```

But the comments on how impractical this is, still make sense.

*Note*  As of PHP 7.3.0 you can use [`array_key_first()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) instead of `reset(); key()`

Comment: Why the complication? `reset` returns the first element, you can work with it directly: https://3v4l.org/9XuRA Either way, the question seems a clear duplicate of just getting the first array element.