# Return first key of associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

I'm trying to obtain the first key of an associative array, without creating a temporary variable via `array_keys()` or the like, to pass by reference. Unfortunately both `reset()` and `array_shift()` take the array argument by reference, so neither seem to be viable results.

With PHP 5.4 I'll be in heaven; `array_keys($array)[0];`, but unfortunately this of course is not an option either.

I could create a function to serve the purpose, but I can only imagine there is some concoction of PHP's `array_*` functions that will **produce the desired result in a single statement**, that I cannot think of or come up with.

So:

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'hello' => 'world');

$firstKey = assorted_functions($array); // $firstKey = 'foo'
```

The reason for the "no reference" clause in my question is only for the fact that I assume `array_keys()` will be required (*if there is a way passing by reference, please fire away*)

I'd use `key()`, but that requires a `reset()` as I'm not sure where the pointer will be at the time of this operation.

---

**Addendum**

I'm following up on a realization I had recently: as I mentioned in the comments, it'll use the memory all the same, so if that's a concern, this question hath no solution.

```
$a = range(0,99999);
var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage()); // int(8644416)
$k = array_keys($a)[0];
var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage()); // int(17168824)
```

I *knew* this, as PHP doesn't have such optimization capabilities, but figured it warranted explicit mention.

The brevity of the accepted answer is nice though, and'll work if you're working with *reasonably* sized arrays.

Comment: I've got a vague hackish idea of `foreach($array as &$key) { return $key; }` possibly accomplishing what you want, but I'm too lazy to test it, and not quite sure what you want.

Comment: @Marc B foreach($array as $key=>$value) { return $key; } should work

Comment: @Marc B - Trying for a single statement to return the value. I could wrap a `foreach` in a `call_user_func(function(){})` but that's a little crazy.

Comment: I just realized: I don't think it matters how you slice it because IIRC now, `array_keys()` creates a copy of the array keys in memory anyway, even with an immediate dereferencing. The single-expression brevity is nice, but the memory consumption still happens.

Comment: I just realized something else; this question has self-deprecated, as if you're still using <= 5.3, you've got problems.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Although `array_shift(array_keys($array));` will work, `current(array_keys($array));` is faster as it doesn't advance the internal pointer.

Either one will work though.

### Update

As @TomcatExodus noted, `array_shift();` expects an array passed by reference, so the first example will issue an error. Best to stick with `current();`

Comment: Bingo. Thank you much on `current(array_keys())`. Just for future reference, an array produced by `array_keys()` or `array_values()` is of course new, and therefore it's pointer is always at the first element, correct?

Comment: Excellent; Thanks again. I must need more coffee, because the more I look at the answer, the more glaringly obvious it seems :) Oh, and a note on `array_shift()`; it doesn't. PHP 5.3.6 with `error_reporting(-1)` issues an error.

Comment: is `key($array)` not faster?

Comment: Maybe. It'll do the job. Use whatever you want.
OP wanted something other than `key()` so this is it.

Comment: current(array_keys($array)); is faster? or the following is faster foreach($array as $key => $val){ echo $key;break;}

Comment: @Developer I dunno. Test them and find out.

If I'm honest though it doesn't really matter.
Use whichever one you prefer.

Comment: The problem in this question is how to return the first key. The answer below by @Brian Graham should be preferred because it:  moves to the first key, and returns it. Nothing else.

Comment: @Aaron I don't see why it's preferential to move the internal array pointer to the first just to return the value when you don't need to. It could in fact lead to unexpected behaviour if used inside control structures like a `while` loop.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [reset](http://php.net/reset) and [key](http://php.net/key):

```
reset( $array );
$first_key = key( $array );
```

or, you can use a function:

```
function firstIndex($a) { foreach ($a as $k => $v) return $k; }
$key = firstIndex( $array );
```

Comment: Thanks @Dark Slipstream - Trying to accomplish in a single statement, no `reset()`.

Comment: You said you can use a function, use that.

Comment: "*could*", but don't want to, especially given the elegant solution. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
array_shift(array_keys($array))
```

Comment: Thanks @RiaD - Strict standards, `array_shift()` requires an array by reference, it's a no go.

Comment: @Tomcat. It's get new array. So your array will be ok. Or it is trigger some errors/notices ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity; yea it issues a notice `Strict Standards`

Comment: OK, thank you, I will know it next time:) [Have not PHP to test]

Comment: array_shift takes array by reference so it will throw error in php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

[`each()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) still a temporary required, but potentially a much smaller overhead than using `array_keys()`.

Comment: Thanks @Orbling - True, there's a plethora of ways using a temporary, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. My struggle has gone from practical to academic :P

Comment: Also, perhaps should have mentioned; the array is not very long, just very deep. The first dimension will likely have 3 - 5 elements, so while `array_keys()` *is* more overhead, it's not producing an enormous array.

Answer (score 0):

What about using array_slice (in combination with array_keys for associative arrays)?

```
$a = range(0,999999);
var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage());
$k = array_keys(array_slice($a, 0, 1, TRUE))[0];
var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage());
var_dump($k);
$k = array_keys($a)[0];
var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage());
```

Gives as output (at least with me):

```
int(36354360)
int(36355112)
int(0)
int(72006024)
int(0)
```