# Access array column by integer instead of associative key name

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-column

How exactly can I apply `array_column()` to always get the first column of an array instead of getting the column by name?

I am seeking something like this is:

```
array_column($array,[0])
```

instead of:

```
array_column($array,"key");
```

Comment: `array_column($array, array_keys($array)[0]);`

Comment: Does not work for me. It seams array_column is hungry for and index name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
array_column($array, array_shift(array_keys($array)));
```

from [Return first key of associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698428/return-first-key-of-associative-array-in-php)

Hope can help! :)

Comment: Does not work for me. It seams array_column is hungry for and index name.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with the `array_column` function, unless you know for certain what the key is for first element of each array is going to be ahead of time.

You'll need to do this with a `foreach()` and use `reset()` to get the first elements.

Answer (score 2):

While `array_column()` will allow you to target a column using an integer, it needs to be an existing integer key.  Otherwise, you will need to determine the first subarray's first key to gain access to that column dynamically.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hH79U))

```
$array = [
    ["foo" => "bar1", "hey" => "now"],
    ["foo" => "bar2", "hey" => "what"],
    [0 => "zero", 1 => "one"]
];

var_export(array_column($array, 'foo'));  // get the column by name
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(array_column($array, 0));  // don't need to be a string
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(array_column($array, key(current($array))));  // access the first subarray, access its key
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(array_column($array, array_shift(array_keys($array))));  // this generates a Notice, and damages the array
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'bar1',
  1 => 'bar2',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'zero',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'bar1',
  1 => 'bar2',
)
---

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /in/hH79U on line 14
array (
  0 => 'zero',
)
```

---

If you use a loop or functional iterator, you can call `current()` or `reset()` to access the first element of each row, but if those first elements have different keys, then this is not *technically* a column of data.  See what I mean in the [demo](https://3v4l.org/Yk0hv) -- you inadvertently grab values from different keys.

```
var_export(array_map('current', $array));
// ['bar1', 'bar2', 'zero']
```