# PHP - get first value from array with single line using native functions

Tags: php

I have a function asdf() that returns an array ["key" => "value"]. I would like to print out value with one line, but reset() function suggested in similar questions does not work for me because reset only takes variable as a argument and doesent accept function. So if i try reset(asdf()) i get an exception: "Only variables should be passed by reference".

So my question is how can i print "value" from asdf() in a single line only using php native functions.

Comment: Shouldn't `asdf()['key']` suffice if you know what the key is in advance?

Comment: Or array_values(asdf())[0] ...

Comment: `asdf()['value']` PHPv >= 5.4

Comment: I guess that might work https://stackoverflow.com/a/6698541/853041

Comment: Forgot to mention that i do not know the key or the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually reset function used to move the array's internal pointer to the first element, I think you must use current function that is return the current element in an array
Try like this

```
print current(asdf());
```

Comment: You have no guarantee this will return the first element unless you call reset first.

Comment: @dhinchliff when you call function it returns a new fresh array that its pointer is pointing to the first element

Comment: This is the best solution for me because my array will always have only one value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
current(array_values(asdf()));
```

It uses `current` to avoid the pass by reference error and `array_values` to ensure the array passed to `current` has the first element as it's current element.

Though unless you have a very good reason assigning the array to a variable and then using reset would be better.