# PHP take array key and value from beginning and put at end

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that has literal_key => value. I need to shift the key and value off the beginning of the array and stick it at the end (keeping the key also).

I've tried:

```
$f = array_shift($fields);
array_push($fields, $f);
```

but this loses the key value.
Ex:

```
$fields = array ("hey" => "there", "how are" => "you");
```

// run above

this yields:

```
$fields = array ("how are" => "you", "0" => "there");
```

(I need to keep "hey" and not have 0) any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't add an associative value to an array with `array_push()`, nor get the key with `array_shift()`.  (same goes for `pop/push`).  A quick hack could be:

```
$fields = array( "key0" => "value0", "key1" => "value1");
//Get the first key
reset($fields);
$first_key = key($fields);
$first_value = $fields[$first_key];
unset($fields[$first_key]);

$fields[$first_key] = $first_value;
```

See it work [here](http://ideone.com/9otOJ).  Some source code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028677/1216976

Comment: Shorter: `reset($fields); list($k, $v) = each($fields); unset($fields[$k]); $fields[$k] = $v;`

Answer (score 2):

You could just take the 0th key `$key` using `array_keys`, then set `$value` using `array_shift`, then set `$fields[$key] = $value`.

Or you could do something fancy like

```
array_merge( array_slice($fields, 1, NULL, true),
             array_slice($fields, 0, 1, true)     );
```

which is untested but has the right idea.