# Get the name of an index in an array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first key in a [possibly] associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array)

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    ['foobar'] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
```

I want to get to name of the first index (foobar). How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't used `each()`, `next()`, `prev()` or in any other manner have you advanced the array pointer:

```
key($array);
```

Answer (score 12):

Other way is,

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

echo $keys[0];
```

Comment: maybe shorten it     $firstKey = array_keys($array)[0];    ?