# Get value of nested key name in php array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have been working with parsing some remote JSON with PHP. I have been able to download the JSON and assign it to a variable, and I have used the array functionality with json_decode:

```
$data = json_decode($remotejson, true);
```

I have then printed the complete array back to verify the contents of the array:

```
echo print_r($data);
```

The array prints back and I can see the keys and values:

```
[files] => Array
    (
        [/photogalleryupload.thumbs/1934307_000001.jpg] => Array
            (
                [source] => derivative
                [format] => Thumbnail
                [original] => moviefile_1934307.mp4
            )
```

**I am trying to get the value of the first nested key name which is "/photogalleryupload.thumbs/1934307_000001.jpg" and assign it to a variable.**

For example, I would like the following code:

```
echo $data['files'][0];
```

To return this:

```
/photogalleryupload.thumbs/1934307_000001.jpg
```

This does not work.

The difficulty I am having is that this value I am trying to return is a 2nd level key name and I have been having trouble finding a way of assigning it to a variable.

Comment: First search for it than ask it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array#tabs

Comment: Thanks for the link Svetlio!  I missed that one in my earlier searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$keys = array_keys($data['files'])
$key = $keys[0]
```