# How would I get the value from a dynamic $_POST variable name?

Tags: php

Basically, I have a website that dynamically creates submit buttons.
Ex:

```
input type="submit" name="test1"

input type="submit" name="test2"
```

and so on....

How would I find out which button was pressed (test1, test2, test3, etc)?

I know you can create multiple forms instead with a hidden value but I would rather just have 1 giant form with multiple submits.

Edit: The buttons are created dynamicly so I don't know how many there will be. It could be test1-test55 so I need to create something that looks at all the possibilities automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change your button generation code, you have a few options.

If your buttons are generated consecutively (1,2,3,...), you can use PHP's magic powers as [documented here (scroll down to "How do I get all the results from a select multiple HTML tag?")](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < MAX; $i++){
    echo '<input type="submit" name="test[]"'." more button code />";
}
```

If your button numbers come from an array, you could do:

```
for ($arr as $i){
    echo '<input type="submit" name="test['.$i.']"'." more button code />";
}
```

In either of these ways, you can then access the form elements in an array. Since these are buttons, and only one of them can be responsible, you can use [this clever method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array) to get the posted value.

```
$the_posted_button_value = reset($_POST['test']);
```

Comment: interesting idea, I like it

Answer (score 1):

you can test which submit is sended with an if or switch statement like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['test1'])){
    //form test1 submitted
}
else{
   if(isset($_POST['test2'])){
    //form test2 submitted
   }
}
```

you can check in all the $_POST key like this

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   if(substr($key,0,4) == 'test'){
      $form_submitted = substr($key,5); //retrieve number of submitted test
   }
}
```

Comment: This is really easy one to get required substring

Answer (score 1):

If you would submit a simple form like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="icebear" value="tickle" />
  <input type="submit" id="doit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

The receiving page will get two variables:

- icebear (with value "tickle")
- doit (with value "SUBMIT")

---

If you have no clue what the name of the submit-button might be, remember that `$_POST` is an array. You can use foreach on it. You can possible filter out the submitbutton on a common prefix that way.

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
  echo "{$key} was submitted with value {$value}<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action ="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="test1" />
    <input type="submit" name="test2" />
    <input type="submit" name="test3" />

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['test1'])){
    echo 'first button is pressed';
}elseif(isset($_POST['test2'])){
    echo 'Second button is pressed';
}

elseif(isset($_POST['test3'])){
    echo 'Third button is pressed';
}

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the `$_POST` array in a different variable, reverse the array, and use [`key()`](http://php.net/key) to get the first key (which is the submit button):

The following should work:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $array = $_POST;
    $array = array_reverse($array);
    $key = key($array); // get first key
    echo $key;
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit3" />
</form>
```

For example, if you submit a value and click any submit button, it should echo the `name` attribute of the submit button that was clicked. The above solution will work regardless of the number of submit buttons in your form.