# How to get the keys in a PHP Array by position?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have an array where I store key-value pair only when the value is not null. I'd like to know how to retrieve keys in the array?

```
  <?php
        $pArray = Array();

        if(!is_null($params['Name']))
            $pArray["Name"] = $params['Name'];

        if(!is_null($params['Age']))
            $pArray["Age"] = $params['Age'];

        if(!is_null($params['Salary']))
            $pArray["Salary"] = $params['Salary'];

        if(count($pArray) > 0)
        {
          //Loop through the array and get the key on by one ...                            
        }
  ?>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: do you want `array_keys()` ?

Answer (score 3):

PHP's foreach loop has operators that allow you to loop over Key/Value pairs. Very handy:

```
foreach ($pArray as $key => $value)
{
    print $key
}

//if you wanted to just pick the first key i would do this: 

    foreach ($pArray as $key => $value)
{
    print $key;
    break;
}
```

An alternative to this approach is to call [`reset()`](https://www.php.net/reset) and then [`key()`](https://www.php.net/function.key):

```
reset($pArray);
$first_key = key($pArray);
```

It's essentially the same as what is happening in the `foreach()`, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array) there is a little less overhead.

Comment: Nice. What if I want just pick the first key? `$firstKey = $pArray[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do:

```
foreach($pArray as $k=>$v){
   echo $k . ' - ' . $v . '<br>';
}
```

And you will be able to see the keys and their values at that point

Answer (score 2):

array_keys function will return all the keys of an array.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the array keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($pArray);
```

To obtain the 1st key:

```
$key = $keys[0];
```

Reference : [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/array_keys)