# Return the index name of key if it is reserved word in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

my problem is a bit similar to some existing topic like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array)
but the solution didn't fit to my problem.
I have an array in function, I want to return the index :

```
protected function commonUploadErrors($key)
    {
         $uploadErrors = array(
                UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => "File is larger than the specified amount set by the server",
                UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    => "File is larger than the specified amount specified by browser",
                UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      => "File could not be fully uploaded. Please try again later",
                UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE      => "File is not found",
                UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR   => "Can't write to disk, due to server configuration ( No tmp dir found )",
                UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE   => "Failed to write file to disk. Please check you file permissions",
                UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    => "A PHP extension has halted this file upload process"
            );

            return $uploadErrors[$key];
        }
```

If **key = 3** I want to return `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` and not `"File is not found"`,
I tried return `key($uploadErrors[$key]);` and return `index_keys$uploadErrors[$key];` but didn't work

I used

```
$result = array_keys($uploadErrors);
     return $result[$key];
```

and I return "3" as well, I think it is the real value of the reserved error code UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE. So I want to return the name of the code not its value, when I echo UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE , I get "2"

Comment: you mean if index is 3, you want to return the key?

Comment: no, I mean what I wrote, I just corrected and added the function header

Comment: Unless you create a reverse map, you'll never get `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` back from anything. Only the *constant's value* will be returned if anything, not the *constant name*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function of PHP, which return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

```
$uploadErrors = array(
    'UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE' => "File is larger than the specified amount set by the server",
    'UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE' => "File is larger than the specified amount specified by browser",
    'UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL' => "File could not be fully uploaded. Please try again later",
    'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE' => "File is not found",
    'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR' => "Can't write to disk, due to server configuration ( No tmp dir found )",
    'UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE' => "Failed to write file to disk. Please check you file permissions",
    'UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION' => "A PHP extension has halted this file upload process"
);
$key = 3;
$newArray = array_keys($uploadErrors);
echo $newArray[$key];//UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
```

So over here `$newArray` will get the array of keys like as

```
Array
(
    [0] => UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
    [1] => UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
    [2] => UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
    [3] => UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
    [4] => UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
    [5] => UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
    [6] => UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
)
```

and just passing the key within `$newArray` variable as `echo $newArray[$key];` will echo the value for that respective key

Comment: I got "3", I think the code UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE equal 3 , see this (http://php.net/manual/fr/features.file-upload.errors.php) so I think the correct is correct but I need to return the name of the error code not its real value

Answer (score 0):

Try use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys)

```
$newArray = array_keys($uploadErrors);
return $uploadErrors[$newArray[$key]];
```

Comment: this will return the value but the OP asked for the constant name

Comment: Then try "return $newArray[$key];" instead of last line

Answer (score 0):

Then you must first place your keys into quotes.
Then extract your array keys into an array, which i called error
Then let your new array keys be the $key variable

```
    $uploadErrors = array(
                'UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE'     => "File is larger than the specified amount set by the server",
                'UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE'    => "File is larger than the specified amount specified by browser",
                'UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL'      => "File could not be fully uploaded. Please try again later",
                'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE'     => "File is not found",
                'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR'   => "Can't write to disk, due to server configuration ( No tmp dir found )",
                'UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE'   => "Failed to write file to disk. Please check you file permissions",
                'UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION'    => "A PHP extension has halted this file upload process"
            );

$errors = array_keys ($uploadErrors);

return $errors[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$uploadErrors` contains constants for the keys, so it will not have the name of the constants as keys, but their values [as indicated in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), e.g.

```
$uploadErrors = [
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => "foo", 
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => "bar", 
    …
]
```

will result in this array:

```
[1 => "foo", 2 => "bar", …]
```

Since the `UPLOAD_ERR_` constants are Core constants, you can get them programmatically and then map their values to the names, e.g. something like this:

```
foreach (get_defined_constants(true)['Core'] as $name => $value) {
    if (strpos($name, 'UPLOAD_ERR_') === 0) {
        $uploadErrorMap[$value] = $name;
    }
}

echo $uploadErrorMap[array_keys($uploadErrors)[3]];
```

This will then output `"UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE"` as a string.

See this demo: https://eval.in/367710

If you want your `$uploadErrors` to contain the actual constant *names*, put them into quotes, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30349215/208809).

---

**Reference:**

- [`get_defined_constants` — Returns an associative array with the names of all the constants and their values](http://php.net/get_defined_constants)
- [`strpos` — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string](http://php.net/strpos)
- [`array_keys` — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array](http://php.net/array_keys)
- [General reference on Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
var_dump(array_slice($input, 3, 1));
```

Comment: this will return the value but the OP asked for the key. Quoting *If key = 3 I want to return UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE and not "File is not found"*