# Get the most frequent value in a string in PHP

Tags: php

So assuming I have this string `198419489151085175` and I want to get the most frequent number appearing on this string, how can I achieve this in PHP? What about the second most frequent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [str_split](http://php.net/str_split), [array_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values) and maybe [arsort](http://php.net/arsort).

Comment: You are looking for the most frequent _digit_, not _number_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in four steps:

1. Use [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to create array from string which contains single digits.
2. Use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) on this splitted string. It returns array which indexes are your digits and values are count of occurences of this digits.
3. Use [arsort()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.arsort.php) to sort array.
4. Get [first element of array using reset() and key() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028677/3233344).

Example:

```
<?php

$string = '198419489151085175';

$splittedString = str_split($string);
$charactersCount = array_count_values($splittedString);
arsort($charactersCount);

reset($charactersCount);
$firstKey = key($charactersCount);

var_dump($charactersCount);
var_dump($firstKey);
```

And result is:

```
array(7) {
  [1]=>
  int(5)
  [9]=>
  int(3)
  [8]=>
  int(3)
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(2)
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [7]=>
  int(1)
}

1 // this is your result
```

Comment: right, but how do I dump only the most frequent digit? not the whole array, like it would just echo "1"

Comment: Why would you answer a question which showed no effort at all?

Comment: @ArioRakip, I have updated my answer. A little advice for future: don't hesitate to try write some code :)