# Get array key of single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$array = ('foo' => 'bar');
```

How do I `echo` 'foo' without using `foreach` or `arraykeys`?

Comment: `echo array_search('bar', $array)`

Comment: `echo reset(array_keys($array));` <- will output the FIRST key of ANY associative array. But, uses `array_keys` - why don't you want to use that?

Comment: @cale_b the question states: "*without using foreach or arraykeys*"

Comment: @TSR - Why do you want to avoid `array_keys`?  Is this some sort of school homework or something?

Comment: `print implode('',$array);` `echo $array['foo'];` `print array_shift($array);`

Comment: @Xorifelse `arraykeys` != `array_keys`, thing he means without the use of an key ;)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I think that is still open to debate, it could be a typo as well.

Comment: @Xorifelse What sence makes `array_keys` here without `reset`? Debate closed ;)

Comment: Ignore my first comment here, i was on the wrong lane. @Xorifelse seems that i did not get it right :)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thanks for the clarity because for a moment there I was confused as `echo str_repeat('*', 4);`

Answer (score 1):

[This is a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array), but you've created the "artificial" construct of not being able to use `array_keys` for some reason, so I want to hilight the options without `array_keys`:

Note that many of the comments have you look for it by the value of `foo`, but I'm assuming you don't / cannot know the values of the array, so these methods do not rely on knowing anything about the array:

There's a few ways without `array_keys`.  Here's just two:

Using [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
reset( $array );
echo key( $array );
```

Or using [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

```
$array = array_flip( $array );
echo reset( $array );
```

And, there's at least one way using [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$keys = array_keys( $array );
echo reset( $keys );
```

There are likely many other approaches.