# How to merge subarrays using keys and sum the values?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge, sum

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm having some trouble with arrays and combining data. I have the following array which has been created from a foreach loop:

```
array(1) {
    [36868]=> int(3)
}
array(1) {
    [2112]=> int(3)
} 
array(1) { 
    [35901]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [6496]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [87]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [36868]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [68]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [9068]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [47]=> int(3) 
}
```

The key in each array is a user ID, so I need to preserve this, but I only want one instance of each key and where there are duplicate keys, sum the values. Like so:

```
array(1) {
    [36868]=> int(6)
}
array(1) {
    [2112]=> int(3)
} 
array(1) { 
    [35901]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [6496]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [87]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [68]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [9068]=> int(3) 
} 
array(1) { 
    [47]=> int(3) 
}
```

The I've tried looping through the array:

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    if ($value[0] == $value[1]) {
        $value[1] += $value[1];
    }
}
```

But with no luck. I've also tried rendering the arrays differently i.e. `[userid]=>1,[score]=>3` and I feel like I'm going round in circles a bit, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: do you need to have separate arrays? or can they be merged?

Comment: @DavidPassmore it can be merged, I had tried that previously as well but haven't had that much luck doing that either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data <-- this is your original array

$result = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function($carry, $item) {
        foreach ($item as $id => $score) {
            if (array_key_exists($id, $carry)) {
                $carry[$id] += $score;
            } else {
                $carry[$id] = $score;
            }
        }

        return $carry;
    },
    []
);
```

If you are sure that each item only contains 1 entry you could also simplify the callback to not use foreach:

```
$result = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function ($carry, $item) {
        $score = reset($item); 
        $id = key($item);

        if (array_key_exists($id, $carry)) {
            $carry[$id] += $score;
        } else {
            $carry[$id] = $score;
        }

        return $carry;
    },
    []
);
```

You could also keep using foreach instead:

```
/** foreach to create a $data array like described below and afterwards do this: **/
$result = [];
foreach($data as $row) {
    $score = reset($row);
    $id = key($row);

    if (array_key_exists($id, $result)) {
        $result[$id] += $score;
    } else {
        $result[$id] = $score;
    }
}
```

This will take an array `$data` like this:

```
array(
    array('1' => 3),
    array('1' => 3),
    array('2' => 3),
);
```

and creates the variable `$result` like this:

```
array(
    '1' => 6,
    '2' => 3,
);
```

Comment: Thanks dbrumann, I've given this a go but all that I get returned is 9 x NULL

`    foreach($results as $key => $value) {

            $data = array($value['id'] => 3);
            
            array_reduce(
                $data,
                function($carry, $item) {
                    foreach ($item as $id => $score) {
                        $carry[$id] += $score;
                    }

                    return $carry;
                },
                []
            );

            var_dump($carry);

    }`

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you couldn't format in the comments :/

Comment: I updated the example. You have to fetch the final result from the function, instead of reusing  `$carry`. Also you don't need a foreach. Just pass in the original array as first argument to `array_reduce()` (replace `$data` with `$results`)

Comment: I don't think it's passing my $data array in to the array_reduce because I can't dump anything out at any point through the each line of code to see what it's doing, it's always NULL or empty. Should I not be able to see at least some data at one of those points?

Comment: Maybe it helps when I write it as foreach instead of using array_reduce. I will update the answer again.

Comment: If this still does not work please show how you assemble the original array or make a `var_dump($data)` and show this, so I can check if maybe the expected array does not look like expected.

Comment: I've changed my $data = array($value['id'] => 3); to $data[] = $value['id']; and that's sorted out my issue. Thanks for your patience dbrumann and for taking the time to help me with this!

Comment: Glad, I could help

Comment: This method generates Notices and is not a professional-grade answer.  https://3v4l.org/DQpkA please see my answer for a clean technique.

Comment: Fair enough. I have updated the answer with a simple way to prevent the notices by making sure the key exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean method that will not produce Notices.  When merge-summing array data the efficient method is to generate temporary keys and use the very fast `isset()` function.  I could have used `current()` and `key()` to access the lone subarray element, but the second foreach control structure is actually faster and more compact.  (Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21219594/2943403 )

Code:  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QkB09))

```
$array = [
    [36868 => 3],
    [2112 => 3],
    [35901 => 3],
    [6496 => 3],
    [87 => 3],
    [36868 => 3],
    [68 => 3],
    [9068 => 3],
    [47 => 3]
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($result[$k])) {
            $result[$k] = $subarray;
        } else {
            $result[$k][$k] += $v;
        }
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    36868 => 6,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    2112 => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    35901 => 3,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    6496 => 3,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    87 => 3,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    68 => 3,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    9068 => 3,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    47 => 3,
  ),
)
```